# How to create inline objects with properties?

Tags: python, instantiation, dynamic-languages

In Javascript it would be:

```js
var newObject = { 'propertyName' : 'propertyValue' };
newObject.propertyName;  // returns "propertyValue"
```

But the same syntax in Python would create a dictionary, and that's not what I want

```
new_object = {'propertyName': 'propertyValue'}
new_object.propertyName  # raises an AttributeError
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I create an object and add attributes to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827623/how-can-i-create-an-object-and-add-attributes-to-it)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
obj = type('obj', (object,), {'propertyName' : 'propertyValue'})
```

there are [two kinds of `type` function uses](http://docs.python.org//library/functions.html#type).

Comment: Documented but obscure behavior. I'm pretty sure 99.9% of Python programmers' initial reaction to seeing this in real code would be "WTF!?".

Comment: Actually, @Laurence, my reaction was, "Woah, I bet that creates a new instance of a made up `'obj'` class that inherits from the `object` with a `'propertyName'` member set to `'propertyValue'` ." And what do you know? I was right! I don't think it's too unintuitive.

Comment: Chris: You admit that you didn't know what the code did. You were only able to guess correctly given the fact that you knew it was supposed to do what the question was asking for. You wouldn't have had that context in real code.

Comment: For completeness, to create an actual *instance* of the type instead of just a type object, this needs a trailing `()`: `obj = type('obj', (object,), {'propertyName' : 'propertyValue'})()`

Comment: @Laurence - I guessed because I didn't know what else it could reasonably do. Context may help, but this statement will probably never be used without context.

Comment: In my opinion, this is an example of code that "accidentally" does something, without in any way **meaning** what it's being used for, and definitely without addressing the design that the OP seems to be struggling with. That's why I downvoted it. I don't think solutions like that should be rewarded or imitated. I cheerfully accept and acknowledge that I'm in the minority!

Comment: It's interesting that this "readable" code has been upvoted so much despite the bug that Greg Hewgill points out.

Comment: @Laurence: there's no *bug*, it works perfectly fine w/o instantiation. I personally don't see why would you want to instantiate this object at all, but of course Python is not preventing you from doing so.

Comment: To the contrary, my initial reaction was WTF.  Especially at the comma after 'object'

Comment: This gives me an error: TypeError: type() argument 2 must be tuple, not type

Comment: for python 3.3+, have a look at Sylvain Leroux [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528932/how-to-create-inline-objects-with-properties-in-python#answer-27931360) below

Comment: The best reason to chose this over the lambda trick is that when I typed the lambda line I was compelled to explain what it was with a code comment. When I use this answer I don't need that comment. That should prove this is the better choice. However, a couple keyword args may help people unfamiliar with the signature: `type('obj', bases=(object,), dict={})`  (the first arg name is actually "what" in python 2.6, so omitted to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ignore my comment about keyword args. Tested and this won't take keyword arguments #unhappydevface  (couldn't edit my last comment to correct it, sorry)

Comment: Since attributes are mostly valid identifiers
`obj = type('obj', (object,), dict(propertyName='propertyValue'))`
Just in case if you want you avoid those curly braces

Comment: In Python 3, you don't need to inherit from `object`, you can just do `obj = type('obj', (), {'property_name' : 'property_value'})`

Comment: @GregHewgill I like completeness.

Answer (score 74):

Python 3.3 added the [`SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) class for that exact purpose:

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace

>>> obj = SimpleNamespace(propertyName='propertyValue')
>>> obj
namespace(propertyName='propertyValue')

>>> obj.propertyName
'propertyValue'
```

In addition to the appropriate constructor to build the object, `SimpleNamespace` defines `__repr__` and `__eq__` ([documented in 3.4](https://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)) to behave as expected.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Far more readable than creating a new `type` and intuitive.

Answer (score 38):

Peter's answer

```
obj = lambda: None
obj.propertyName = 'propertyValue'
```

Comment: @ManelClos he is creating a function object that returns none which you could see with obj(). The function object can have properties.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if there's a built-in way to do it, but you can always define a class like this:

```
class InlineClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dict):
        self.__dict__ = dict

obj = InlineClass({'propertyName' : 'propertyValue'})
```

Answer (score 7):

I like [Smashery's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528932/how-to-create-inline-objects-with-properties-in-python/1528939#1528939) idea, but Python seems content to let you modify classes on your own:

```
>>> class Inline(object):
...     pass
...
>>> obj = Inline()
>>> obj.test = 1
>>> obj.test
1
>>>
```

Works just fine in Python 2.5 for me. Note that you do have to do this to a class derived from `object` - it won't work if you change the line to `obj = object`.

Comment: Yep, you can do that - but for some strange reason, you just can't use object() - you have to create your own class.

Comment: if you want an inline class, you can use `obj = lambda: None`, which is bizarre, but will perform the necessary tasks...

Comment: @Peter - I didn't know that. However, now that I see it, I like SilentGhost's answer much better.

Comment: I removed the constructor to show the shortest way to achieve it

Comment: @Jader - Fair enough. It looks better without it.

Comment: @Smashery: the "strange reason" is that type `object` is the root of the object inheritance tree, and if it had an associated dict to hold properties, all objects in Python would have to have an associated dict.  I do actually wish there was a standard type that just made an empty container class, but it's pretty darn easy to just declare your own.

Answer (score 5):

SilentGhost had a good answer, but his code actually creates a new object of metaclass type, in other words it creates a class. And classes are objects in Python!

```
obj = type('obj', (object,), {'propertyName' : 'propertyValue'})
type(obj)
```

gives

```
<class 'type'>
```

To create a new object of a custom or build-in class with **dict** attributes (aka properties) in one line I'd suggest to just call it:

```
new_object = type('Foo', (object,), {'name': 'new object'})()
```

and now

```
type(new_object)
```

is

```
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

which means it's an object of class Foo

I hope it helps those who are new to Python.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy in Python to declare a class with an `__init__()` function that can set up the instance for you, with optional arguments.  If you don't specify the arguments you get a blank instance, and if you specify some or all of the arguments you initialize the instance.

I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495666/how-to-define-a-class-in-python/1495740#1495740) (my highest-rated answer to date) so I won't retype the explanation.  But, if you have questions, ask and I'll answer.

If you just want a generic object whose class doesn't really matter, you can do this:

```
class Generic(object):
    pass

x = Generic()
x.foo = 1
x.bar = 2
x.baz = 3
```

An obvious extension would be to add an `__str__()` function that prints something useful.

This trick is nice sometimes when you want a more-convenient dictionary.  I find it easier to type `x.foo` than `x["foo"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another viable option is to use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

message = namedtuple('Message', ['propertyName'], verbose=True)
messages = [
    message('propertyValueOne'),
    message('propertyValueTwo')
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class test:
    def __setattr__(self,key,value):
        return value


myObj = test()
myObj.mykey = 'abc' # set your property and value
```

Comment: There is no need to define __setattr__, see Chris response