# Is there an existing Python class that can hold any user attributes?

Tags: python, struct

I can use this when I need multiple objects with different attributes:

```
class struct(object):
   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
      for key,val in kwargs.items():
         setattr(self,key,val)
```

But I'm wondering if there isn't a built-in already?

Comment: it seems you're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528932/how-to-create-inline-objects-with-properties-in-python/1528993#1528993

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless I'm not understanding your question, isn't this what we use a `dict` for? Sure, it's notationally slightly different, but an object's attributes are internally still stored in a `dict` (namely `__dict__`). It's a matter of notation.

But, if you insist, then this is one way to do it:

```
>>> class struct(dict):
...     def __getattribute__(self, key):
...         return self[key]
... 
>>> s = struct(a=5, b=7)
>>> s.a
5
```

Note I'm using [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) instead of [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__). The reason for this, is that otherwise we cannot store attributes with names such as `get` and `keys`, since these are methods defined by [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

The [solution by SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528932/how-to-create-inline-objects-with-properties-in-python/1528993#1528993) is probably more efficient and works just as well, without resorting to the use of `__getattribute__`. The code then becomes:

```
>>> def struct(**kwargs):
...     return type('Struct', (object,), kwargs)
... 
>>> s = struct(a=5, b=7)
>>> s.a
5
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain why you're not using a dictionary for this.

```
x = {}
x.update([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])
print x
```

result

```
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

or

```
x.update(a=2, b=4, c=6)
```

results in

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 6, 'b': 4}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have wondered the same thing.  I enjoy the convenience of `x.foo` instead of `x["foo"]`; a single period is far easier to type (and get correct) than all of `[""]`.

The advantage of a dict is that *anything* can be a key.  (Well, anything hashable.)  But when I have a bunch of values I want to just bundle together, the key names I pick are valid identifiers anyway.

Here's the basic version of this idea:

```
class struct(object):
    pass

x = struct()
x.foo = 1
```

As long as you are going to this much trouble, you might as well add the `__init__()` that handles `kwargs` for convenient initialization.  But I'm lazy and I was hoping for something built-in.

I tried this, which doesn't work:

```
x = object()
x.foo = 1   # raises AttributeError exception
```

I asked about it, and the answer I got was that `object` is the root of all types in Python; it is as small as possible.  If it could act like a class instance, with its own `__dict__` attribute, then every object ever created in Python would need an attached `__dict__`.

I would have liked to see `struct` added as a built-in for Python 3.x.  But I understand why it was not: keeping the language small and clean is a worthy goal, and this feature is trivially easy to code up yourself.

Comment: Nice analysis. Let me add two things: (1) this property of `object`, that it doesn't have `__dict__`, can also be had for other classes, by defining `__slots__` (see http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots for more); (2) with respect to your last paragraph: `import this` states: *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*