# How do I get ("return") a result (output) from a function? How can I use the result later?

Tags: python, function, return

Suppose I have a function like:

```
def foo():
    x = 'hello world'
```

How do I get the function to return `x`, in such a way that I can use it as the input for another function or use the variable within the body of a program? I tried using `return` and then using the `x` variable in another function, but I get a `NameError` that way.

---

<sub>For the specific case of communicating information *between methods in the same class*, it is often best to store the information in `self`. See [Passing variables between methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520075/) for details.</sub>

Comment: I really recommend you read the python tutorial here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) statement to return a value from a function, this **does not** make it so that the returned variable (value) becomes available in the [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) of the caller. To use the value in the caller you can either use it directly in a statement or capture the value in a variable.

Here's some code to demonstrate this:

```py
def foo():
    x = 'hello world'
    return x  # return 'hello world' would do, too

foo()
print(x)   # NameError - x is not defined outside the function

y = foo()
print(y)   # this works

x = foo()
print(x)   # this also works, and it's a completely different x than that inside
           # foo()

z = bar(x) # of course, now you can use x as you want

z = bar(foo()) # but you don't have to
```

Answer (score 8):

### Effectively, there are two ways: directly and indirectly.

The direct way is to `return` a value from the function, as you tried, and let the calling code use that value. This is *normally what you want*. The natural, simple, direct, explicit way to get information back from a function is to `return` it. Broadly speaking, the **purpose of** a function is to compute a value, and `return` signifies "this is the value we computed; we are done here".

#### Directly using `return`

The main trick here is that `return` returns a **value, not** a variable. So `return x` **does not** enable the calling code to use `x` after calling the function, and **does not** modify any existing value that `x` had in the context of the call. (That's presumably why you got a `NameError`.)

After we use `return` in the function:

```
def example():
    x = 'hello world'
    return x
```

we need to write the calling code to use the return value:

```
result = example()
print(result)
```

The other key point here is that a call to a function is an **expression**, so we can use it the same way that we use, say, the result of an addition. Just as we may say `result = 'hello ' + 'world'`, we may say `result = foo()`. After that, `result` is our own, *local* name for that string, and we can do whatever we want with it.

We can use the same name, `x`, if we want. Or we can use a different name. The calling code doesn't have to know anything about how the function is written, or what names it uses for things.<sup>1</sup>

We can use the value directly to call another function: for example, `print(foo())`.<sup>2</sup> We can *return* the value directly: simply `return 'hello world'`, without assigning to `x`. (Again: we are returning *a value, not a variable*.)

The function can only `return` once each time it is called. `return` terminates the function - again, we just determined the result of the calculation, so there is no reason to calculate any further. If we want to return multiple pieces of information, therefore, we will need to come up with a single *object* (in Python, "value" and "object" are effectively synonyms; this doesn't work out so well for some other languages.)

We can [make a tuple right on the return line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345995); or we can use a dictionary, a [`namedtuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608) (Python 2.6+), a [`types.simpleNamespace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161275) (Python 3.3+), a [`dataclass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263) (Python 3.7+), or some other class (perhaps even one we write ourselves) to associate names with the values that are being returned; or we can [accumulate values from a loop in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/); etc. etc. [The possibilities are endless.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883).

On the other hand, the function `return`s whether you like it or not (unless an exception is raised). If it reaches the end, it will implicitly `return` the special value `None`. You [may or may not want to do it explicitly instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/).

---

### Indirect methods

Other than `return`ing the result back to the caller directly, we can communicate it by modifying some existing object that the caller knows about. There are many ways to do that, but they're all variations on that same theme.

If you want the code to communicate information back this way, please just let it return `None` - **don't** also use the return value for something meaningful. That's [how the built-in functionality works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254).

In order to modify that object, the *called* function also has to know about it, of course. That means, having a *name* for the object that can be looked up [in a current *scope*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978). So, let's go through those in order:

#### Local scope: Modifying a passed-in argument

**If** one of our parameters is mutable, we can just mutate it, and rely on the caller to examine the change. This is *usually* not a great idea, because it can be hard to reason about the code. It looks like:

```
def called(mutable):
    mutable.append('world')

def caller():
    my_value = ['hello'] # a list with just that string
    called(my_value)
    # now it contains both strings
```

If the value is an instance of our own class, we could also assign to an attribute:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def called(mutable):
    mutable.value = 'world'

def caller():
    test = Test('hello')
    called(test)
    # now test.value has changed
```

Assigning to an attribute [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827623) for built-in types, including `object`; and it might not work for some classes that explicitly prevent you from doing it.

#### Local scope: Modifying `self`, in a method

We already have an example of this above: setting `self.value` in the `Test.__init__` code. This is a special case of modifying a passed-in argument; but it's part of how classes work in Python, and something we're expected to do. Normally, when we do this, the calling won't actually check for changes to `self` - it will just use the modified object in the next step of the logic. That's what makes it appropriate to write code this way: we're still presenting an *interface*, so the caller doesn't have to worry about the details.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self._words = ['hello']
    def add_word(self):
        self._words.append('world')
    def display(self):
        print(*self.words)

x = Example()
x.add_word()
x.display()
```

In the example, calling `add_word` gave information back to the top-level code - but instead of looking for it, we just go ahead and call `display`.<sup>3</sup>

See also: [Passing variables between methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520075/)

#### Enclosing scope

This is a rare special case when using nested functions. There isn't a lot to say here - it [works the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447947) as with the global scope, just using [the `nonlocal` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875) rather than `global`.<sup>4</sup>

#### Global scope: Modifying a global

Generally speaking, *it is a bad idea to change anything in the global scope after setting it up in the first place*. It makes code harder to reason about, because anything that *uses* that global (aside from whatever was responsible for the change) now has a "hidden" source of input.

If you still want to do it, the syntax is straightforward:

```
words = ['hello']
def add_global_word():
    words.append('world')

add_global_word() # `words` is changed
```

#### Global scope: Assigning to a new or existing global

This is *actually a special case* of modifying a global. I don't mean that assignment is a kind of modification (it isn't). I mean that when you assign a global name, Python automatically updates a dict that represents the global namespace. You can get that dict with `globals()`, and you can modify that dict and it will actually impact what global variables exist. (I.e., the return from `globals()` is the dictionary itself, not a copy.)<sup>5</sup>

[**But please don't**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164). That's even worse of an idea than the previous one. If you really need to get the result from your function by assigning to a global variable, [use the `global` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379) to tell Python that the name should be looked up in the global scope:

```
words = ['hello']

def replace_global_words():
    global words
    words = ['hello', 'world']

replace_global_words() # `words` is a new list with both words
```

#### Global scope: Assigning to or modifying an attribute of the function itself

This is a rare special case, but now that you've seen the other examples, the theory should be clear. In Python, functions are mutable (i.e. you can set attributes on them); and if we define a function at top level, it's in the global namespace. So this is really just modifying a global:

```
def set_own_words():
    set_own_words.words = ['hello', 'world']

set_own_words()
print(*set_own_words.words)
```

We shouldn't really use this to send information to the caller. It has all the usual problems with globals, and it's even harder to understand. But it can be useful to set a function's attributes from within the function, in order for the function to remember something in between calls. (It's similar to how methods remember things in between calls by modifying `self`.) The `functools` standard library does this, for example in the `cache` implementation.

#### Builtin scope

This doesn't work. The builtin namespace doesn't contain any mutable objects, and you can't assign new builtin names (they'll go into the global namespace instead).

---

### Some approaches that don't work in Python

#### Just calculating something before the function ends

In some other programming languages, there is some kind of hidden variable that automatically picks up the result of the last calculation, every time something is calculated; and if you reach the end of a function without `return`ing anything, it gets returned. That doesn't work in Python. If you reach the end without `return`ing anything, your function returns `None`.

#### Assigning to the function's name

In some other programming languages, you are allowed (or expected) to assign to a variable with the same name as the function; and at the end of the function, that value is returned. That still doesn't work in Python. If you reach the end without `return`ing anything, your function still returns `None`.

```
def broken():
    broken = 1

broken()
print(broken + 1) # causes a `TypeError`
```

It might *seem like* you can at least use the value that way, if you use the `global` keyword:

```
def subtly_broken():
    global subtly_broken
    subtly_broken = 1

subtly_broken()
print(subtly_broken + 1) # 2
```

But this, of course, is just a special case of assigning to a global. And there's a big problem with it - the same name can't refer to two things at once. By doing this, the function *replaced its own name*. So [it will fail next time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/):

```
def subtly_broken():
    global subtly_broken
    subtly_broken = 1

subtly_broken()
subtly_broken() # causes a `TypeError`
```

#### Assigning to a parameter

Sometimes people expect to be able to assign to one of the function's parameters, and have it affect a variable that was used for the corresponding argument. However, this does not work:

```
def broken(words):
    words = ['hello', 'world']

data = ['hello']
broken(data) # `data` does not change
```

Just like how Python returns **values, not variables**, it also *passes* values, not variables. `words` is a local name; by definition the calling code doesn't know anything about that namespace.

One of the working methods that we saw is to *modify* the passed-in list. That works because if the *list itself* changes, then it changes - it doesn't matter what name is used for it, or what part of the code uses that name. However, *assigning* a new list to `words` **does not** cause the existing list to change. It just makes `words` start being a name for a different list.

For more information, see [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> At least, not for getting the value back. If you want to use keyword arguments, you need to know what the keyword names are. But generally, the point of functions is that they're an *abstraction*; you only need to know about their *interface*, and you don't need to think about what they're doing internally.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> In 2.x, `print` is a statement rather than a function, so this doesn't make an example of calling another function directly. However, `print foo()` still works with 2.x's print statement, and so does `print(foo())` (in this case, the extra parentheses are just ordinary grouping parentheses). Aside from that, 2.7 (the last 2.x version) has been [unsupported since the beginning of 2020](https://endoflife.date/python) - which was nearly a 5 year extension of the normal schedule. But then, this question was originally asked in 2010.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup>Again: if the purpose of a method is to update the object, **don't** also `return` a value. Some people like to return `self` so that you can "chain" method calls; but in Python this is considered poor style. If you want that kind of "fluent" interface, then instead of writing methods that update `self`, write methods that create a new, modified instance of the class.</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup> Except, of course, that if we're modifying a value rather than assigning, we don't need *either* keyword.</sup>

<sup><sup>5</sup> There's also a `locals()` that gives you a dict of local variables. However, this **cannot** be used to make new local variables - the behaviour is undefined in 2.x, and in 3.x the dict is created on the fly and assigning to it has no effect. Some of Python's optimizations depend on the local variables for a function being known ahead of time.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> def foo():
    return 'hello world'

>>> x = foo()
>>> x
'hello world'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `global` statement and then achieve what you want without returning value from 
the function. For example you can do something like below:

```
def foo():
    global x 
    x = "hello world"

foo()
print x
```

The above code will print "hello world".

But please be warned that usage of "global" is not a good idea at all and it is better to avoid usage that is shown in my example.

Also check this related discussion on about usage of [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146557/do-you-use-the-global-statement-in-python) statement in Python.

Comment: Technically, this is a solution to Seafoid's question, but pythonically, it's the worst-case-scenario (as you already pointed out).