# UnboundLocalError: local variable … referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import hmac, base64, hashlib, urllib2
base = 'https://.......'

def makereq(key, secret, path, data):
    hash_data = path + chr(0) + data
    secret = base64.b64decode(secret)
    sha512 = hashlib.sha512
    hmac = str(hmac.new(secret, hash_data, sha512))

    header = {
        'User-Agent': 'My-First-test',
        'Rest-Key': key,
        'Rest-Sign': base64.b64encode(hmac),
        'Accept-encoding': 'GZIP',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    return urllib2.Request(base + path, data, header)
```

Error:
   File "C:/Python27/btctest.py", line 8, in makereq
    hmac = str(hmac.new(secret, hash_data, sha512))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hmac' referenced before assignment

Somebody knows why? Thanks

Comment: Writing `hmac = str(hmac.new(secret, hash_data, sha512))` means that the name `hmac` is reassigned locally (module names **do not** get a separate namespace, just like builtins; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605. Therefore, the code is trying to use `hmac.new` with the **local** `hmac` (**not** the global module), **before** it has been defined, as in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

If you assign to a variable anywhere in a function, that variable will be treated as a local variable *everywhere* in that function.  So you would see the same error with the following code:

```
foo = 2
def test():
    print foo
    foo = 3
```

In other words, you cannot access the global or external variable if there is a local variable in the function of the same name.

To fix this, just give your local variable `hmac` a different name:

```
def makereq(key, secret, path, data):
    hash_data = path + chr(0) + data
    secret = base64.b64decode(secret)
    sha512 = hashlib.sha512
    my_hmac = str(hmac.new(secret, hash_data, sha512))

    header = {
        'User-Agent': 'My-First-test',
        'Rest-Key': key,
        'Rest-Sign': base64.b64encode(my_hmac),
        'Accept-encoding': 'GZIP',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    return urllib2.Request(base + path, data, header)
```

Note that this behavior can be changed by using the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords, but it doesn't seem like you would want to use those in your case.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `nonlocal` is Python 3+ only, is it not?  OP tagged this 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining the `hmac` variable within the function scope, so the global variable from the `import` statement isn't present within the function scope.  Renaming the function-scope `hmac` variable should fix your problem.