# 'str' object is not callable,how to deal?

Tags: python, django

When I run my Python Django app, I receive an error:

> 'str' object is not callable

I've tried the solutions here: [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python), but they don't work for me. I'm trying to run the Django book sample:

**view.py:**

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def current_time(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><head></head><body>%s</body></html>" % str(now)
    return HttpResponse(html)

def hello(request,name):
    return HttpResponse("Hello django")

def what(request):
    return HttpResponse("what's the problem django?")
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from hello_django.views import current_time,hello,what


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^time/$','current_time'),
    url(r'^what/$','what'),
    url(r'^hello/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)','hello'),
)
```

This is the URL I'm trying: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/what/`.

**Stack Trace:**

```
TypeError at /what/
'str' object is not callable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/what/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object is not callable
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response, line 115
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.4
Python Path:    
['D:\\Developer Center\\PyCharm\\helloDjango',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mysql_python-1.2.4-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'D:\\Developer Center\\PyCharm\\helloDjango',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']
Server time:    Tue, 7 Jan 2014 11:44:30 +0330
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Please show us the *full* traceback of the exception.

Comment: The code posted here doesn't exhibit your problem unless you somehow assigned to `django.http.HttpResponse` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: See the "Switch to copy-and-paste view" line in your error message? You really want to do that next time; click on that link and get a text version of just the traceback to copy into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give the actual **view** to `url()`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^time/$', current_time),
    url(r'^what/$', what),
    url(r'^hello/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', hello),
)
```

Note that I removed the quotes around `what` and the other view functions.

You can still use strings in the `url()` configurations, but then you need to use a `<modulename>.<viewname>` syntax or name the module in the first argument to `patterns()` (the string), and then you also don't need to import the functions:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^time/$', 'hello_django.views.current_time'),
    url(r'^what/$', 'hello_django.views.what'),
    url(r'^hello/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'hello_django.views.hello'),
)
```

or

```
urlpatterns = patterns('hello_django.views',
    url(r'^time/$', 'current_time'),
    url(r'^what/$', 'what'),
    url(r'^hello/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'hello'),
)
```

See the [detailed URL dispatcher documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/).

Comment: I want to accept it as answer and it tells me you can not accept answer before four minutes! lol, What a Quick answer,Quick Check,quick accept! thanks man.