# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. Even though there is nothing called 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Before I start there are many other exact questions but none of the answers are adequate to my problem. The class/function `log.info('foo')` runs once with no problem however the second time it's called it get the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I found that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python) has the same problem as me, however I don't have anything called str. I have tested with with other funcions i.e war.

My code:

```
import praw
import sys
import traceback
from accounts import *

class logging:

    def info(self, log):
        self.info = '\033[94m'
        self.rs = '\033[0m'
        print self.info, 'INFO: ', self.rs

    def warn(self, log):
        self.warn = '\033[93m'
        self.rs = '\033[0m'
        print self.warn, 'WARNING: ', self.log, self.rs

    def critical(self, log):
        self.critical = '\033[91m'
        self.rs = '\033[0m'
        print self.critical, 'CRITICAL: ', log, self.rs

def read_accounts():
    with open('accounts.py') as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass

    i += 1
    accounts = {}

    while i > 0:
        ac = globals()['account_%s' %i]
        index = ac.find(':')
        uname = ac[0:index]
        password = ac[index+1:len(ac)]
        accounts[uname] = password
        i -= 1

    log.info('Usernames loaded successfully! Usernames loaded:')
    print  accounts

def main():
    log.info('Initilizing reddit accounts from file...')
    try:
        read_accounts()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        log.critical('Can not read accounts! Make sure format is correct!')
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = logging()
    main()
```

Also I know there is a logging module in python but I wanted to do my own thing!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a module-level variable named `log` in your `accounts` module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `logging` class redefines all its instance methods as strings:

```
class logging:

    def info(self, log):
        self.info = '\033[94m'  # self.info is not a function anymore
        self.rs = '\033[0m'
        print self.info, 'INFO: ', self.rs
```

So the first time you call `log.info`, it calls the `info` function. The second time, it tries calling the string `'\033[94m'`.

Just use a different name for that instance variable in all your methods - or don't make it an instance variable at all. You're redefining it every time the method is called anyway:

```
class logging:

    def info(self, log):
        info_prefix = '\033[94m'  # no conflict
        self.rs = '\033[0m'
        print info_prefix, 'INFO: ', self.rs
```