# tqdm: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, tqdm

I import tqdm as this:

```
import tqdm
```

I am using tqdm to show progress in my python3 code, but I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 15, in <module>
    for dir in tqdm(os.listdir(path), desc = 'dirs'):
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is the code:

```
path = '../dialogs'
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for dir in tqdm(dirs, desc = 'dirs'):
    print(dir)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)

Comment: It almost seems like the devs should make a custom error for this because it is such a common mistake.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

The error is telling you are trying to call the module. You can't do this.

To call you just have to do

```
tqdm.tqdm(dirs, desc='dirs')
```

to solve your problem. Or simply change your import to

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

But, the important thing here is to review the documentation for what you are using and ensure you are using it properly.

Comment: made me laugh at my self lol

Answer (score 19):

You Have Used Only **tqdm**, Actually it is **tqdm.tqdm**
So, Try

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for dir in tqdm(dirs, desc = 'dirs'):
print(dir)
```

Comment: Wow! Actually solved my issue. I do stupid imports and then regret later. I should have checked earlier.

Answer (score 9):

tqdm is a module (like matplotlib or pandas) that contains functions. One of these functions is called tqdm. Therefore, you have to call tqdm.tqdm to call the function within the module instead of the module itself.

Comment: The most useful answer (give a fish for today vs. explain how to fish for ever).

Answer (score 1):

```
from tqdm import tqdm
with open(<your data>, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for _, line in enumerate(tqdm(f)):
       pass
```

Comment: Please add some context to this, possibly an explanation why the code should be altered like that to help people with similar problems in the future. Thank you!