# What is causing this TypeError to happen?

Tags: python-3.x

So, I have been working on a Python implementation of Wheel of Fortune for quite some time, and after a while of testing what I have so far, it throws out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    wheel_of_fortune()
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 50, in wheel_of_fortune
    player1firstturn(player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, 0, 0, 0)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 190, in player1firstturn
    player1do(prize, choice, player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 229, in player1do
    player1firstturn(player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 87, in player1firstturn
    player1firstturn(player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 167, in player1firstturn
    player2firstturn(player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 439, in player2firstturn
    player2do(prize, choice, player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 478, in player2do
    player2firstturn(player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 416, in player2firstturn
    player3firstturn(player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 723, in player3firstturn
    player3do(prize, choice, player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 762, in player3do
    player3firstturn(player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/e.py", line 693, in player3firstturn
    player1(player1choice, player1, player2, player3, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

can anyone explain the "error-causer" to me?
BTW, what I have so far is here:
https://gist.github.com/HarrySlaughter/d8481874ec401cb0a78defd75ad9fd72

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: you are calling `wheel_of_fortune` which must be a variable that contains `str` object.

Comment: You have a variable called `player1` as a parameter which is a `str` and are trying to use it as a function. You likely meant to call `player1do` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes can cause this error.
Check this out.

[str object not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)

It would be helpful if you provide your code