# How to fix "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to rank words used in one document by their frequency in another document.

As I am a beginner, I asked someone to help me with the code, and this is what they sent me. It's giving me an error.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
occurences = defaultdict(int)
with open("booksandtranscripts.txt","r") as file:
    booksandtranscripts = file.read()
    for word in booksandtranscripts.split(" "):
        occurences[word] += 1
words_and_frequencies = []
with open("allminow.txt","r") as file:
    allminow = file.read()
    for word in allminow.split(" "):
        words_and_frequencies.append((occurences[word],[word]))
for frequency,word in sorted(words_and_frequencies):
    print("%s : %i %" (word, frequency))
```

I expected it to print the words of one document alongside them the frequencies of those words in the other document. I know this code doesn't export csv, but I was planning on attempting to add that too.

Here is the error I got:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 15, in <module>
    print("%s : %i %" (word, frequency))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: I think that is supposed to be `print("%s : %i" % (word, frequency))`. The `%` must be between the string and the arguments.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! However (and I know this is unrelated to the question so feel free to ignore), sometimes it prints words with "\n" behind them and sometimes without...Do you know why that happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)

Comment: @handras, not a duplicate of that question, since there are two different root causes. Here it's a simple typo. In the question you are referring to, the builtin `str` function was redefined.

Comment: @YoussefAbdelmohsen, the words with "\n" are probably just the last words of each line. Since you read the file at once it includes all line-endings as well, and you don't remove them anywhere. Hint: take a look at [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines), [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) or [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), for example. You could use any of them to remove the end-of-line characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your print format is wrong:

> **Basic formatting** Simple positional formatting is probably the most common use-case. Use it if the order of your arguments is not likely
>   to change and you only have very few elements you want to concatenate.
>
> Since the elements are not represented by something as descriptive as
>   a name this simple style should only be used to format a relatively
>   small number of elements.

Old

```
print("%s : %i %%" % (word, frequency)) # To print the % sign you need to 'escape' it with another % sign
```

New

```
print ('{} : {} %'.format(word, frequency))

print(f"{word} : {frequency} %")
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I got a percent sign near every number but that's okay. Do you know how I might be able to export the print to CSV?

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is in the syntax of the print string representing the variables. I don't understand the c-style %-thing, so I just suggest to use the current f-string syntax instead:

```
print(f"{word}: {frequency} %")
```