# How to read a string in a bitstream in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing the following string in my output file:

```
bitstream.add("stri", 32)
```

where

```
def add(self, data, length):
    s = ''
    if (type(data) == str):
        for char in data:
            b = bin(ord(char))[2:]
            s = s + "{:0>8}".format(b)
    else:
        s = bin(data)[2:]
        if (len(s) < length):
            resto = length - len(s)
            for _ in range(0, resto):
                s = '0' + s
    s = s[0:length]
    self.cache = self.cache + s
    self.flush()
```

Later on I need to read the string from the output file. I use Python `struct unpack` module as follows:

```
   from struct import unpack
   key_length_bytes = 32
   key = ""
   for _ in range(0, key_length_bytes):
      carattere = chr(unpack('>B', in_file.read(1))[0])
      key = "%s%s" (key, carattere)
```

I get

```
key = "%s%s" (key, carattere)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Thank you for any help you could provide.

Comment: read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python#14936426

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `%` sign.
`key = "%s%s" (key, carattere)` needs to be changed into

```
key = "%s%s" % (key, carattere)
```

Comment: Thank you, problem solved! I also edited the question since the loop to read the string was not correct.