# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while using driver.page_source().text

Tags: python, selenium, typeerror

I am trying to extract tables from a website for multiple dates. I am using the following code to do so.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'C:/Users/asus/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)

URL = 'URL'
driver.get(URL)

driver.find_element_by_id('calender1').click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_slctr).click() #css_selector for date
driver.find_element_by_id('show').click()
driver.page_source().text
# # print(html)
```

But the above code is giving a TypeError as follows.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-a6ffd4caf5cf> in <module>
      9 
     10 # driver.page_source().text
---> 11 driver.page_source().text
     12 # # print(html)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I tried the same element selectors in Rselenium and I was able to extract the desired table. 
Since I'm new to Python I'm not sure what this error means! According to what I read [here](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-fix-python-error-typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python) it seems to me that, this error occurs when we try to redefine a built-in function(Please correct me, if i misunderstood). But I believe, I did not redefine any built-in function here. So why am I getting this error? And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page_source` is a property, not a function. It returns `str` so no need to call `text` on it

```
source = driver.page_source
```

Answer (score 0):

[page_source](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) is a property of the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance. So you can't invoke `page_source` as a function. You have tried:

```
driver.page_source()
```

Hence you see the error:

```
---> 11 driver.page_source().text
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

---

### Solution

As a solution you can use either of the following solutions:

- Print the `page_source`:

  ```
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Save the `page_source` in a variable and print:

  ```
  html = driver.page_source
  print(html)
  ```

Comment: `page_source` is a property, not a function.