# Trying to clean a couple columns of a DF to prepare for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm testing the code below.

```
features = df[['body','review_text']].values
labels = df['num_reviews'].values


processed_features = []
for sentence in range(0, len(features)):
    # Remove all the special characters
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(features[sentence]))

    # remove all single characters
    processed_feature= re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', processed_feature)

    # Remove single characters from the start
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', processed_feature) 

    # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', processed_feature, flags=re.I)

    # Removing prefixed 'b'
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', processed_feature)

    # Converting to Lowercase
    processed_feature = processed_feature.lower()

    processed_features.append(processed_feature)
```

I encounter an error on this line:

```
processed_feature = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(features[sentence]))
```

The error message is:  `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

The code that I am testing is from this link.

https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-sentiment-analysis-with-scikit-learn/

What is the easiest way to fix this?  Or, is there an altogether better way to do this kind of text-cleaning exercise?  Thanks.

Comment: somewhere a variable with name `str` is assigned

Comment: `str` is a builtin function in python so you can only get that error if you have `str=<something>` in your code`

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out; you can call a function but you can't call a string.  Makes sense.  Thanks guys!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)