# Selenium error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape a website with Selenium. After I got past the login, I try delaying, finding an element, and printing it's text with the `.text` property. Below is my code:

```
from login_info import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/users/aliallam/Desktop/scraper test/chromedriver")
url = 'https://results.decisiondeskhq.com/2020/primary/colorado/president'
driver.get(url)



# Bypass loading page and click login link
delay = 10  # seconds
login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-text-btn')))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", login_button)
##

# Login
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input')
email.send_keys(login_email)

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/input')
password.send_keys(login_pass)

login_button_actual = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/form/button/div')
login_button_actual.click()
##


results_table = WebDriverWait(driver,delay).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'overview-info'))
)
print(results_table.text())

#results_table = driver.find_element_by_id('overview-info')
#print(results_table.text)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aliallam/Desktop/scraper test/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(results_table.text())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it just `results_table.text`?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to call a string, but it's possible to access the text property of `results_table` object.

Instead of:

```
results_table.text()
```

try accessing the text property:

```
results_table.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below answer, your xpath is also wrong for a table and you need   print results_table.text to print your table.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://results.decisiondeskhq.com/2020/primary/colorado/president')
driver.maximize_window()
delay = 10
login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-text-btn')))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", login_button)
##

# Login
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input')
email.send_keys("username")

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/input')
password.send_keys("password")

login_button_actual = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Log In')]")
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(login_button_actual).click().perform()

results_table = WebDriverWait(driver,delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "(//table[@class='v-datatable v-table theme--light''])[1]"))

print results_table.text
```