# Python 3.8 treats "open" as imported openpyxl method instead of built-in function

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have some code in which I need to open files that are sometimes .csv files, but other times .xlsx files.  I've imported [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to handle the Excel files.

On switching from Python 3.7 to 3.8, I've found that using the *open* keyword (which I intend to refer to [Python's built-in *open* function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)) results in calls to openpyxl's *load_workbook()* function, which isn't what I want.

Here's a code snippet that demonstrates the issue:

```
from openpyxl import *
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

fileName = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Select file.')

with open(fileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    print('fileName')
```

This code is supposed to:

- Pop up a dialog box prompting you to select a file
- Open that file in Python
- Print its file name

In 3.7, that's exactly what it does; the script runs fine and prints out the file name.  However, when I run it in 3.8, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Python Scripts\test\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open(fileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

The *load_workbook()* method is mad because I passed it an 'encoding' argument, which it wasn't expecting.  If I remove the 'encoding' argument, I instead get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Python Scripts\test\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open(fileName, 'w') as file:
  File "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 312, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 94, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .csv file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

Now it's mad because I'm trying to open a .csv file, and openpyxl can only open Excel files.  But I don't understand why openpyxl is even involved here - all I've done is import the module at the top!  The *open* keyword is supposed to be calling Python's built-in function, not a method from openpyxl.

---

Questions:

- Why is *load_workbook()* getting called under these circumstances in 3.8 (but not in 3.7)?
- How can I convince Python to use its built-in *open* function instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "import \*" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)

Comment: The question has **nothing to do with** the Python version. It has to do with the *openpyxl* version, since some version of openpyxl decided to add an `open` alias for `load_workbook`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Why did I see different behavior when switching Python versions, then?  Does (or did) openpyxl install different versions of itself depending on what Python version you have?  I *believe* I installed the module using a basic *pip install* command on both versions at the same time, but this was a long time ago, so i could be misremembering.

Comment: Re: dupe, the linked question seems like good advice that would have let me avoid this issue, but doesn't directly answer the "why is this happening?" question.  I'm indifferent whether this gets counted as a dupe; I got my answer to it long ago.

Comment: It's the best I could find for "Q. why has a built-in been overridden? A. Because you used a star-import that defines that name". It's one of many common forms of *shadowing* of names. See also e.g. [Why does code like `str = str(...)` cause a TypeError, but only the second time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/).

Comment: Packages can specify the python version they require so it's quite possible for different versions of the package to be installed when using different versions of Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openpyxl.open` is an alias for `openpyxl.load_workbook`, [added](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/commit/d405d28aa2ae373e5484387487c30488038cab2a) in version 3.0. You've imported that alias with `from openpyxl import *`. (Your Python 3.7 setup was probably using an old openpyxl version.)

Stop using `import *`! This is a textbook example of what goes wrong when you use `import *`. Use `import openpyxl` and access the contents explicitly with `openpyxl.whatever`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and fixed it by restricting my import. Since I was only using the `load_workbook` function, I replaced `from openpyxl import *` with `from openpyxl import load_workbook`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `io.open`. You have to `import io` at the top of the script.

Comment: That will work, but it's probably better to avoid shadowing `open` in the first place.