# Python, user input as a function argument not working: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, function, typeerror, callable

I just started learning Python yesterday, so this is probably a stupid question. Nonetheless I have been searching for the solution for a while and couldn't find it!
Here is my very basic program:

```
def year(year):
  try:
    print(int(year))
  except:
    print("you did not enter a year")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  year = input("what year? ")
  year(year)
```

The thing is that, when I am running it in the terminal I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fonctions.py", line 24, in <module>
    year(year)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Could someone help me sort this out ?
Thank you!
Olivier

Comment: You're overwriting your own function by setting `year` to the string that returns from `input`

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)

Comment: Unfortunately no. The person was redefining the built-in Python name of the string type: str()

Comment: That second question is more suited for a new separate question. The problem might seem similar based on the error-message, but they are two vastly different problems. The first problem is a namespace-problem while the second is a variable-typing problem.

Comment: @OlivierGirardot I've rolled back your edit. Please in future don't edit your question to something completely different, especially after someone has answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the input variable name, because in here python is interpreting that it is calling the `year` variable, not the function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  year_val = input("what year? ")
  year(year_val)
```

Comment: While this will solve the problem, I think the more Pythonic solution would be to rename the function to something like `is_year` instead. It makes the code more readable and easier to debug in the future.

Comment: Yes, this did solve my problem. It was definitely a rookie mistake :) Thanks!

Comment: But to be honest, I have the same problem on another function, and it doesn't involved any confusion between the function name and the arguments' names. I will add it to this question.