# how to resolve te str not callable in this case?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm working on this code ("https://dlab.berkeley.edu/blog/scraping-new-york-times-articles-python-tutorial").
I upgrade the code but I'm having a problem with this code

```html
Amnesty_all = ()
for i in range (1980, 2014):
  print ("processing" + str(i) +"...")
  Amnesty_year = get_articles(str(i), 'Amnesty International')
  Amnesty_all  = Amnesty_all + Amnesty_year
```

this is the error

```html
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-9d931b0be5bb> in <module>()
      1 Amnesty_all = ()
      2 for i in range (1980, 2014):
----> 3   print ("processing" + str(i) +"...")
      4   Amnesty_year = get_articles(str(i), 'Amnesty International')
      5   Amnesty_all  = Amnesty_all + Amnesty_year

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: The above code does not seem to have any errors, if this is not all of your code, it would be nice to give us some more info, maybe you defined a `str` before?

Comment: Yes, you've accidentally reassigned either `print` or `str` somewhere before this.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes it's not my code sorry during the redaction of the question i deleted some informations.the code is from this source https://dlab.berkeley.edu/blog/scraping-new-york-times-articles-python-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you should try to replace:

```
print ("processing" + str(i) +"...")
```

With:

```
print ("processing {}...".format(i))
```

Based on [previous issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python), looks like you created `str` variable or smth :)

Comment: Hi I followed your advice `Amnesty_all = []
for i in range(1980,2014):
  print ("processing {}...".format(i))
  Amnesty_year =  get_articles(str(i),"amnesty")
  Amnesty_all = Amnesty_all + Amnesty_year
  print(type(i))` but the now I'm receiving this error **TypeError: must be str, not bytes** for the line `Amnesty_year = get_articles(str(i),"amnesty")`. Any advice ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using and what `get_articles` function does?

Comment: I'm using Colab so if using python Python 3.6.9 and 
Python 2.7.17,  The function **get_articles** accepts a year in string format (e.g.'1980')
    and a query (e.g.'Amnesty International') and it will 
    return a list of parsed articles (in dictionaries)
    for that year.

Comment: If you're getting `bytes` error it means that you messed up your Python2/3 collab. Also, you can't convert bytes to string using `str`, bytes need to be `decode`d.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and it partialy worked  ` Amnesty_all = ()
  for i in range (1980, 2014):
    theta = b"i".decode("utf8")
    print ("processing".format(theta))
    Amnesty_year = get_articles(theta, 'Amnesty International')
    Amnesty_all  = Amnesty_all + Amnesty_year` but i'm receiving this error 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable