# Scope of variables in python decorators - changing parameters

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following decorator with parameters:

```
from functools import wraps
def pdecor(p):
    def decorator(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            p -= 1
            return fn(*args, **wargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Trying to use the decorator results in :

```
>>> @pdecor(1)
... def run(): pass
...
>>> run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in wrapper
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

Why can't I change the `p`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python variable scope question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447947/is-it-possible-to-modify-variable-in-python-that-is-in-outer-but-not-global-sc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you assign to `p` inside `wrapper`, Python treats the `p` inside `wrapper` as local to `wrapper`.  In Python 3 you can use `nonlocal p` to mark `p` as referenced from an outer scope.  In Python 2 there is no way to assign to the intermediate p, although you can get a reference to the same value by passing it into the nested functions as a keyword argument (e.g., `def decorator(fn, p=p)`).

However, it's not clear what you're getting at with this anyway.  `p` is already only local to `pdecor`.  No code outside `pdecor` can access `p`, so decrementing it won't have any effect on any code elsewhere.  So whether you can decrement `p` or not, it won't really accomplish anything.

Comment: Originally I want to write a "retry" decorator that retries running function given amount of times. So I would try running `fn` and decrement `p` it `fn` raises exception until either I'm out of `p` retries or `fn` succeeds.  
  
However now I'm happy that Python did not let me doing so, otherwise all executions of the decorated function would share the same retry counter, right?