# Are assignments made at function call in Python?

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment

While building a parameterized decorator, I had not realized reassignments to passed in arguments within nested functions were not allowed in Python.  Looking further, I realized this is also true for simple functions as well.  I have reduced the demonstration to the following nested function:

```
def a(s):
    def b():
        def c():
#             nonlocal s                         # fix
            print(s)
#             while s:
#                 s -= 1                         # uncommenting raises UnboundLocalError 
            print(s)
            return None
        return c()
    return b()

a(3)
# 3
# 3
```

I would like the following desired output by adding the commented `while` loop:

```
a(3)
# 3
# 0
```

Next, uncommenting the two lines of the `while` loop gives the following error, which suggests that reassigning a value to `s` raises an error:

```
<ipython-input-37-7141eb599936> in c()
      3         def c():
      4 #             nonlocal s                 # fix
----> 5             print(s)
      6             while s:
      7                 s -= 1                   # uncommenting raises UnboundLocalError

UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

Finally, uncommenting `nonlocal` fixes this issue and gives the desired output as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078288/scope-of-variables-in-python-decorators-changing-parameters).

Although the problem is solved, I would like to understand the source of the issue.  I noticed the traceback points to the first use of the parameterized argument `s` (e.g. `print(s)`), rather than pointing to the lines that actually cause the error (i.e. the `while` loop/assignment).

I suspect that upon calling a function, Python first establishes assignments of the local scope.  Assignments then take higher precedence over or override inherited variables from the outer scopes.  Thus without an assignment to `s`, the outer `s` is used.  By contrast, with an assignment, `s` is redefined at the function call, and any reference before the initial assignment will raise an error.  Is this correct, or can someone explain what Python is actually doing?

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at how Python executes the file line-by-line using http://www.pythontutor.com!

Comment: @Windmill I appreciate the suggestion.  At the moment, pythontutor shows that `s` is available in frame of `a()`, but it does not clearly indicate how `s` is observed in the nested functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function contains an assignment to a variable (including augmented assignments such as `-=`, that variable is automatically local, unless explicitly declared as `global` (or `nonlocal`).  If there are no assignments, it's automatically global, without needing any declaration (since it could hardly be a local variable when there's no source of a value for it).  This analysis is performed before any code is generated, so you get situations like this where a subsequent line of code can cause an earlier line to become an error.

Comment: This confirms my suspicion.  Are you aware of a reference that that supports this?