# Python global and local variables

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

In Python 2.7, running the following code:

```
def f():
    a = a + 1

f()
```

gives the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    f()
  File "test.py", line 2, in f
    a = a + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

But if I change the code to below:

```
def f():
    a[0] = a[0] + 1

f()
```

I get the different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    f()
  File "test.py", line 2, in f
    a[0] = a[0] + 1
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Why is Python considering `a` is a local variable when it is an `int`, global when `list`? What's the rationale behind this?

P.S.: I was experimenting after reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447947).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is found in the documentation on [the assignment statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> Assignment of an object to a single target is recursively defined as
>   follows.
>
> If the target is an identifier (name) *(e. g. `a = a + 1`)*:
>
> - If the name does not occur in a global statement in the current code
>     block: the name is bound to the object in the current local namespace.
> - Otherwise: the name is bound to the object in the current global
>     namespace.
>
> The name is rebound if it was already bound. This may cause
>   the reference count for the object previously bound to the name to
>   reach zero, causing the object to be deallocated and its destructor
>   (if it has one) to be called.
>
> ...
>
> If the target is a subscription *(e. g. `a[0] = a[0] + 1`)*: The primary expression in the
>   reference is evaluated. It should yield either a mutable sequence
>   object (such as a list) or a mapping object (such as a dictionary).
>   Next, the subscript expression is evaluated.

In `f`<sub>1</sub> Python sees that you are binding some value to `a`, sees that `a` has not been used in a `global a` statement in this scope and prepares a local variable.  Then it attempts to evaluate the expression `a + 1`, looks up the variable `a` and finds an uninitialized local variable.  This results in the `UnboundLocalError`.

In `f`<sub>2</sub> Python sees that you are assigning some value to a subscription of the variable `a`.  It looks up that variable in the local namespace and fails to find it.  It then walks up the non-local namespaces (closures) until it reaches the global namespace.  Once it fails to find `a` in the global namespace it throws a `NameError`.

Comment: I think the error has nothing to do with the assignment in g. I have edited the question removing unrelated statements.

Comment: @fossilet - apologies that I mistook your question - I've update my answer, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try to do something like this :

```
def f(a):
    a += 1
    print a

def g():
    a = 3
    f(a)

g()
```