# How to allow exec to access free variables in nested method in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have to access free variables in `exec` in nested method in python(2.6)

```
def outerF():
    la = 5
    def innerF():
        str1 = "print(la)"
        exec (str1) in globals(),locals()
    innerF()
outerF()
```

The expected result is 5 but I am getting the following error

> NameError: name 'la' is not defined

Comment: You can't. Not in Python 2, where there is no concept of marking variables you bind to as nonlocal.

Comment: Moreover, `la` is **not a free variable**. Variables are only marked as free when the compiler sees that there is a nested function that uses the name, and there is no such use here at compile time. By the time `exec` is executed it's too late to change this.

Comment: Closure : It is a function object that remembers values in enclosing scopes even if they are not present in memory. To solve this you need to use **nonlocal** keyword You can check use of **nonlocal** and details about **Closure** in following link for more info https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures

Answer (score 0):

for python 2.6

```
def outerF():
    la={'y': 5} # exec take argu as dict and in 2.6 nonlocal is not working, 
    # have to create dict element and then process it 
    def innerF():

        str1 = "print({})".format(la['y'])
        exec (str1) in globals(),locals()
    innerF()
outerF()
```

Comment: Care to add some explanation to your undocumented answer? I didn't downvote though.

Comment: You are now accessing a global variable, not the free variable in the closure of inner

Comment: How to do it without making la global?

Comment: @Bazingaa hope this is explanatory  enough

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga updated the code  using the global or nonlocal way

Comment: @VickyGupta usng nonlocal

Comment: It is python 2.6 @prashantrana

Comment: @VickyGupta updated for 2.6

Answer (score 0):

Use nonlocal to access outer function's variable in nested functions as:
[Python Global, Local and Nonlocal variables](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables)

```
def outerF():
    la = 5
    def innerF():
        nonlocal la    #it let the la variable to be accessed in inner functions.
        str1 = "print(la)"
        exec (str1) in globals(),locals()
    innerF()
outerF()
```

Comment: It is python 2.6

Comment: if you don't want to use Global, you might find your answer here than :)
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447947/is-it-possible-to-modify-variable-in-python-that-is-in-outer-but-not-global-sc/8448029`

Answer (score 0):

Please try using nonlocal statement for your variable.
Like this:

```
def outerF():
    la = 5
    def innerF():
        nonlocal la
        str1 = "print(la)"
        exec (str1) in globals(),locals()
    innerF()
outerF()
```

More info could be found here: [Python Global, Local and Nonlocal variables](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables)

Comment: It is giving error: nonlocal la
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @VickyGupta nonlocal isn't available in Python 2. If you're using an old version of Python, please specify that in your question.

Comment: @VickyGupta, try to avoid global vars as much as possible. May be passsing it as an argument with the default value or using *args is better idea.