# How can I use `return` to get back multiple values from a loop? Can I put them in a list?

Tags: python, function, return

I have some code that prints data from a global dictionary named `cal`:

```
def show_todo():
    for key, value in cal.items():
        print(value[0], key)
```

However, I want to use this code as part of a Discord bot. In order for the bot to work properly, I need to `return` the data to another function that will actually send the message to the Discord chat. Using `print` like above means that the message is displayed in my local console window, and the chat just sees `None`.

I tried to fix it by using `return` instead:

```
def show_todo():
    for key, value in cal.items():
        return(value[0], key)
```

but this way, the for loop does not work properly. I only get at most one key-value pair from the dictionary.

How can I fix this so that all of the data is returned?

Comment: You can call a function within the for loop without directly printing or returning the value

Comment: This question has become a canonical duplicate target for questions about returning multiple values from code including a `for` loop. As such, I have edited it somewhat artificially, to make it as useful as possible in that context.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Using a `return` inside of a loop will break it and exit the function even if the iteration is still not finished.

For example:

```
def num():
    # Here there will be only one iteration
    # For number == 1 => 1 % 2 = 1
    # So, break the loop and return the number
    for number in range(1, 10):
        if number % 2:
            return number
>>> num()
1
```

In some cases we need to break the loop if some conditions are met. However, in your current code, breaking the loop before finishing it is unintentional.

Instead of that, you can use a different approach:

### Yielding your data

```
def show_todo():
    # Create a generator
    for key, value in cal.items():
        yield value[0], key
```

You can call it like:

```
a = list(show_todo())  # or tuple(show_todo())
```

or you can iterate through it:

```
for v, k in show_todo(): ...
```

### Putting your data into a list or other container

Append your data to a list, then return it after the end of your loop:

```
def show_todo():
    my_list = []
    for key, value in cal.items():
        my_list.append((value[0], key))
    return my_list
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
def show_todo():
    return [(value[0], key) for key, value in cal.items()]
```

Comment: How would I extract the data? If i use print(show_todo()[0]) it'd print out ['Science', 'Friday']. How do I remove those brackets? Sorry, but I'm really new to python and programming in general.

Comment: `print()` will only print. But instead of using print, use `my_list.append(...)`. In other words append what'll print in a list then return it.

Answer (score 7):

Use a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) syntax (excellent explanation on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1878539)):

```
def show_todo():
    for key, value in cal.items():
        yield value[0], key

for value, key in show_todo():
    print(value, key)
```