# What does python's return statement actually return?

Tags: python

I want to know how we get the value returned by a  function - what the python return statement actually returns.

Considering following piece of code:

```
def foo():
    y = 5
    return y
```

When invoking `foo()`, we get the value `5`.

```
x = foo()
```

`x` binds the integer object `5`.

What does it mean? What does the return statement actually return here? The `int` object `5`? Or variable name `y`? Or the binding to the object `5`? Or something else?

How do we get the value returned by the return statement?

Comment: `y` is a reference to integer object `5`. `5` is also a reference to the integer object `5`. Everything is reference.

Comment: The `int` object 5 is returned

Comment: This question seems to get used sometimes as a duplicate target for people who have a `return` statement inside a loop and want to return multiple values (although I can't understand why). That is a (completely and utterly) different problem; please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> x binds the integer object 5.

Yes, `x` is a variable holding a reference to the integer object 5, which `y` also holds the reference to.

> What does the return statement actually return here? The int object 5?
>   Or variable name y? Or the binding to the object 5? Or something else?

To be precise, it is the *reference* to integer object 5 being returned. As an example, look at this:

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     y = 5
   ...:     print(id(y))
   ...:     return y
   ...: 

In [2]: x = foo()
4297370816

In [3]: id(x)
Out[3]: 4297370816
```

> How do we get the value returned by the return statement?

By accessing the *reference* that `return` passes back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any doubts you can always go to Python's REPL and experiment with values and functions. There is a `type()` instruction that can be used with values as well as with functions, for example:

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 19 2017, 13:09:21) 
[GCC 7.1.1 20170622 (Red Hat 7.1.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def foo():
...     y=5
...     return y
... 
>>> type(foo())
<class 'int'>
```

Regarding your `foo()` function, `y` is a local binding that holds the value `int`. `return` statement returns a value of variable `y` and this binding is not known outside the `foo()` function scope.