# Why doesn't this very simple function work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why doesn't this very simple function work? I get NameError: name 'x' is not defined

```
def myfunc2():
    x=5
    return x

myfunc2()
print(x)
```

Comment: do `x = myfunc2()` instead of just `myfunc2()`

Comment: The function does work. It just doesn't do what you expect it to. You need to learn about *scope* and how return works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does python's return statement actually return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275046/what-does-pythons-return-statement-actually-return)

Answer (score 1):

You've declared and defined `x` inside of `myfunc2` but not outside of it, so `x` is not defined outside of `myfunc2`.

If you'd like to access the value of `x` outside of `myfunc2`, you can do something like:

```
a = myfunc2()
print(a) # 5
```

I'd suggest reading up on [variable scope in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python).

Comment: I think to further clarify to a beginner this issue, one should change the names of variables. Otherwise, there's 2 different x's and the difference between the apparently 2 same things is confusing. Just my 2c.

Answer (score -4):

The x in myfunc2 is declared as a local. In order for this script to work, you can declare x as global:

```
def myfunc2():
    global x
    x = 5
    return x

myfunc2()
print(x)
>>>5
```

Hope this helps.