# querying from table and returning as JSON

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to query from a table in my db. I'm using python btw. I want to return them as JSON over a loop.

But I only return one row from my table, which looks like this:

```
{
    "content": "content1", 
    "date": "date1", 
    "title": "title1"
}
```

Here's my code:

```
ann = Announcements.query.all()

for data in ann:
    return jsonify({'date': data.date, 'title': data.title, 'content': data.content })
```

I want to return something like this:

```
{
    "content": "content1", 
    "date": "date1", 
    "title": "title1"
},
{
    "content": "content2", 
    "date": "date2", 
    "title": "title2"
},
{
    "content": "content3", 
    "date": "date3", 
    "title": "title3"
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have a `return` inside your for loop, so your loop will terminate after only one iteration.  You probably want to create a list, then in your loop append your dictionary to the list.  After the loop return the json-encoded list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create a list firstly. And append all your data and jsonify. If you return jsonify you should use method.

```
def jsonify(ann):
    my_list = []
    for data in ann:
      my_list.append({'date': data.date, 'title': data.title, 'content': data.content })
    return jsonify(my_list)
```

Otherwise you should print in a loop your data like this

```
for data in ann:
   print(jsonify({'date': data.date, 'title': data.title, 'content': data.content }))
```

[Look at this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564729/4711785)

Comment: Yes, I agree Ilja. JSON has two data type:Object and Array. If you have problem just about brackets, you can replace with substrings.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes I've just confirmed it. My bad I'll delete my comment