# How to use the return statement in a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

In my program, I have a timer function, it uses a while loop. I want it to return the time past from its start while looping, without stopping the function.

```
def timer():
    time_ = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        time_ += 1
        return time_
```

But return breaks the loop.
I need something like return to start another function if the time is x :

```
if timer() < 20:    
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: create a boolean `check = False` then `while True: ..... check = some condition` and finally `if check: do something else: do something else`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to use a return statement in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/python-how-to-use-a-return-statement-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `yield`. It's like `return`, but can be used in a loop. For more details, see [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/4518341)

```
def timer():
    time_ = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        time_ += 1
        yield time_

for i in timer():
    if i < 20:    
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

you reset `time_ = 0` every time you call `timer()` function.

Try to instantiate `time_` outside of the function so it can keep incrementing next time you call `timer()`function.

```
time_ = 0

def timer ():
    time_ += 1
    return time
```