# returning all elements of a list in a function without getting None as last value

Tags: python, list

I there a way to return all my elements of a list?

```
def singular(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print(i)

a = singular(list)
print(a)
```

with print(i) i get after all elements None as value
with return i only the first value

Comment: Your code does not update anything. It just prints stuff out.

Comment: `print` is not the same as `return`.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything so why are you trying to print it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Comment: ah, so because return needs for updating a structure. k. and in a function - just printing values out -without None as last print value - is therefore not possible. correct?

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of [How can I use `return` to get back multiple values from a for loop? Can I put them in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`None` is not returned as the last value from your list. It gets printed from your `print(a)` statement, and it is printing `None`, because the function doesn't `return` anything. There is the code that possibly outputs what you want:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def singular(passed_list):  # Dont use 'list' as variable name
    for i in range(len(passed_list)):
        print(i)
    return passed_list

a = singular(my_list)
print(*a)
```

Comment: i wanna just print my numbers of my list. - without the list. - so  it isnt possible without -None- as last value? yes, i know my function doesnt return anything, because i wanted to avoid to just return a new list [with, numbers]

Comment: Edited. Check it out