# Loop stops after first iteration

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I need to check if every string in a list is in titlecase. If yes return True - if not return False. I have written the following:

```
word_list=["ABC", "abc", "Abc"]

def all_title_case(word_list): 
   for word in word_list: 
        if not word.istitle():
            return False
        else: 
            return True 

print(all_title_case(word_list))
```

My problem is that it seems that the loops stops after the first string (which i guess is because of return?)

How could i make it go over the whole list?

*I am new to python

thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you think `return` does?

Comment: You only want to `return True` after you've fully completed the for loop.

Comment: FYI you can use `all()` to do what you want in just one line - `print(all(word.istitle() for word in word_list))`.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning immediately in both the `if` and `else` blocks. That ends the loop in both cases.

You should only return in the `if` block. If you make it through the entire loop without returning, you know that all the words are title case.

```
def all_title_case(word_list): 
    for word in word_list: 
        if not word.istitle():
            return False
    return True
```

You can also use the `all()` function instead of a loop.

```
def all_title_case(word_list): 
    return all(word.istitle() for word in word_list)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both solutions are solving it!

Answer (score 0):

Return statement ends the execution of your function, if you return True only when your for iteration is done you will have what you want

In other words your return statement ends your for loop, you can read some about it on this question:
[How to use a return statement in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/how-to-use-a-return-statement-in-a-for-loop)

```
word_list=["ABC", "abc", "Abc"]

def all_title_case(word_list): 
   for word in word_list: 
        if not word.istitle():
            return False

   return True 

print(all_title_case(word_list))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is solving it!