# How to end a loop?

Tags: python

I have created a game of rock, paper scissors, where the user plays vs the computer. Right now it is stuck in an infinite loop and because I'm new to python I don't know how to end the loop. I've added an example below of how I want it to go. Any help would be appreciated! :)

```py
import random

print("Welcome to the game of rock, paper, scissors!")  

newLi = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]  
numRandom = newLi[random.randint(0, 3)]
user = False 

while not user:
    user = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? \nAnswer: ") 
    if user == numRandom: 
        print("It's a tie! Please try again.")  
    elif user == "Rock" or user == "rock":
        if numRandom == "Paper":  
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "covers", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "smashes", numRandom)
    elif user == "Paper" or user == "paper":
        if numRandom == "Scissors":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "cuts", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "covers", numRandom)
    elif user == "Scissors" or user == "scissors":
        if numRandom == "Rock":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "smashes", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "cuts", numRandom)
    else:
        print("Invalid answer! Try again.")  

endGame = input("Would you like to keep playing? Y or N\nAnswer: ")

if endGame == "Y"
    KEEP PLAYING
else:
    STOP PLAYING
```

Comment: Why not just create a variable to store a score and decide that when the score reaches that number (either for the player or the computer), the game ends?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a return statement in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/how-to-use-a-return-statement-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: Alternatively, [break](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)

Comment: You can use break statment to stop loops. Just google a little you will find tons of info about it

Answer (score 0):

I've added a user input variable *rounds_to_play* that asks the user how many rounds they would like to play, this variable will decrement per round until the game is done. You could also add a bool *is_playing* and say *while is_playing* and then set the bool to be false when the game is over.

```
import random

print("Welcome to the game of rock, paper, scissors!")

new_lst = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
num_random = new_lst[random.randint(0, 3)]
rounds_to_play = int(input("How many rounds would you like to play: "))

while rounds_to_play > 0:
    user_input = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? \nAnswer: ")
    if user_input == num_random:
        print("It's a tie! Please try again.")
    elif user_input == "Rock" or user_input == "rock":
        if num_random == "Paper":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", num_random, "covers", user_input)
        else:
            print("Good job! You're the winner!",
                  user_input, "smashes", num_random)
    elif user_input == "Paper" or user_input == "paper":
        if num_random == "Scissors":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", num_random, "cuts", user_input)
        else:
            print("Good job! You're the winner!",
                  user_input, "covers", num_random)
    elif user_input == "Scissors" or user_input == "scissors":
        if num_random == "Rock":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!",
                  num_random, "smashes", user_input)
        else:
            print("Good job! You're the winner!",
                  user_input, "cuts", num_random)
    else:
        print("Invalid answer! Try again.")
        rounds_to_play += 1

    rounds_to_play -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to get endgame and if else loop inside the while loop.
Then you could use a flag variable to start and stop your while loop

```
import random

print("Welcome to the game of rock, paper, scissors!")

newLi = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
numRandom = newLi[random.randint(0, 3)]
flag = True
while flag:
    user = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? \nAnswer: ")
    if user == numRandom:
        print("It's a tie! Please try again.")
    elif user == "Rock" or user == "rock":
        if numRandom == "Paper":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "covers", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "smashes", numRandom)
    elif user == "Paper" or user == "paper":
        if numRandom == "Scissors":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "cuts", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "covers", numRandom)
    elif user == "Scissors" or user == "scissors":
        if numRandom == "Rock":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "smashes", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "cuts", numRandom)
    else:
        print("Invalid answer! Try again.")

    endGame = input("Would you like to keep playing? Y or N\nAnswer: ")

    if endGame == "Y":
        flag =True
    else:
        flag = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I concluded that you want to create a rock-paper-scissor "game" in python that will keep going as long as the `endGame = 'Y'`, so defining the `user = False` on top of your code is not necessary.

You need to define the `endGame` to be `'Y'` at first instead. No need to add any additional flag as well.

For the clarity, I change the variable `endGame` to `continueGame`.

Therefore, this should be the algorithm/mechanism of the game in steps:

1. Define the rock, paper and scissors
2. Get user's choice
3. Pick one randomly among rock, paper and scissors.
4. Print the response
5. Ask the user whether they want to continue the game:

   - If `Y`, get back to step 2.
   - If `N`, end the runtime.

Thus, you need to count the random inside the loop. Otherwise, the result would always be the same every time the user wants to play the game again and again.

You can sanitize the case to make it easier for checking, i.e. using `.lower()` to lowercase the user input.

```
import random

print("Welcome to the game of rock, paper, scissors!")

newLi = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
continueGame = 'Y'

while continueGame = 'Y':
    user = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? \nAnswer: ")
    numRandom = newLi[random.randint(0,3)]
    if user.lower() == numRandom:
        print("It's a tie! Please try again.")
    elif user.lower() == "rock":
        if numRandom == "Paper":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "covers", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "smashes", numRandom)
    elif user.lower() == "paper":
        if numRandom == "Scissors":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "cuts", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "covers", numRandom)
    elif user.lower() == "scissors":
        if numRandom == "Rock":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "smashes", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "cuts", numRandom)
    else:
        print("Invalid answer! Try again.")

    continueGame = input("Would you like to keep playing? Y or N\nAnswer: ")
```

Answer (score -1):

Added an extra flag 'loop' which will end the loop when user says 'N' to continue. If user says 'Y' to continue it will set user to False to get into other while loop.

```
import random

print("Welcome to the game of rock, paper, scissors!")  

newLi = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]  
numRandom = newLi[random.randint(0, 3)]
user = False 
loop = True

while(loop):
    while not user:
        user = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? \nAnswer: ") 
        if user == numRandom: 
            print("It's a tie! Please try again.")  
        elif user == "Rock" or user == "rock":
            if numRandom == "Paper":  
                print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "covers", user)
            else :
                print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "smashes", numRandom)
        elif user == "Paper" or user == "paper":
            if numRandom == "Scissors":
                print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "cuts", user)
            else :
                print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "covers", numRandom)
        elif user == "Scissors" or user == "scissors":
            if numRandom == "Rock":
                print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "smashes", user)
            else :
                print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "cuts", numRandom)
        else:
            print("Invalid answer! Try again.")  

    endGame = input("Would you like to keep playing? Y or N\nAnswer: ")

    if endGame == "N":
        loop=False
    else:
        user=False
```

Comment: This answer requires elaboration. Why is this an answer? What does it do differently? How does that difference or the differences yield the desired result?

Comment: Added an extra flag to break the loop if user says no to continue

Comment: You also changed the indentation, which in Python is a big deal. Please edit the post to add the elaboration.

Answer (score -1):

You are stuck in a loop because Python considers code block based on indentation. In you code

```
import random

print("Welcome to the game of rock, paper, scissors!")  

newLi = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]  
numRandom = newLi[random.randint(0, 3)]
user = False 

while not user:
    user = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? \nAnswer: ") 
    if user == numRandom: 
        print("It's a tie! Please try again.")  
    ...  

endGame = input("Would you like to keep playing? Y or N\nAnswer: ")

if endGame == "Y"
    KEEP PLAYING
else:
    STOP PLAYING
```

If you notice, `endGame = ...`, `if endGame`, and your `else` statements are all on the same level of indentation as your initial `while` loop. This means they are not actually a part of your loop, but instead would execute only after the loop has been closed.

Step 1, is to indent all of that to be included inside of the code block.

Step 2 is to switch `KEEP PLAYING` with `continue` and `STOP PLAYING` with `break`.

If you're doing that, you can just change your `while` loop to be `while True`

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm) is a good link for flow controls of loops.

---

Not related to question, but since we're here to help, you're going to run into some comparison issues if you allow a user to type a capitalized or lowercase answer.

Look into [.lower()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_lower.asp) and consider using lowercase for everything in this scenario.

---

End code should look like:

```
import random

print("Welcome to the game of rock, paper, scissors!")  

newLi = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]  
numRandom = newLi[random.randint(0, 3)]
user = False 

while True:
    user = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? \nAnswer: ") 
    if user == numRandom: 
        print("It's a tie! Please try again.")  
    elif user == "Rock" or user == "rock":
        if numRandom == "Paper":  
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "covers", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "smashes", numRandom)
    elif user == "Paper" or user == "paper":
        if numRandom == "Scissors":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "cuts", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "covers", numRandom)
    elif user == "Scissors" or user == "scissors":
        if numRandom == "Rock":
            print("Aw! You lost. Try again!", numRandom, "smashes", user)
        else :
            print("Good job! You're the winner!", user, "cuts", numRandom)
    else:
        print("Invalid answer! Try again.")  

    endGame = input("Would you like to keep playing? Y or N\nAnswer: ")

    if endGame == "Y"
        continue
    else:
        break
```