# How to get a serie of request.POST values

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

In the following views.py:

```
def valores(request):
    global peso_unitario, preco_unitario
    peso_unitario=[]
    preco_unitario=[]

    N=a
    print('N='+str(N))

    for i in range(N):
        peso_u=request.POST['peso_u']
        preco_u=request.POST['preco_u']

        if peso_u.isdigit() and preco_u.isdigit():
            c = int(peso_u)
            d = int(preco_u)
            peso_unitario.append(c)
            preco_unitario.append(d)
            print(a)
            print(preco_unitario)
            if i<N-1:
                return render(request, 'valores.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'pacote.html',
                              {'peso_unitario': peso_unitario, 'preco_unitario': preco_unitario})
        else:
            res = 'Apenas numero.'
            return render(request, 'pacote.html', {'res': res})
```

I have a function that receives a global value N=a, this value was received from the user, now I need to receive N times the both values in request.POST loop, but each time the user needs to enter the values. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: See [How can I use `return` to get back multiple values from a for loop? Can I put them in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/how-can-i-use-return-to-get-back-multiple-values-from-a-for-loop-can-i-put-th)

Answer (score 0):

This is your python code, as per your problem you need to make a loop in your template to take input from user `N` times or maybe take values of `peso_u` and `preco_u` in a list whose length must be equal to `N` here.