# My right angle pattern is incomplete, why am I missing a few bottom rows or columns?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, pattern-matching

I'm trying to output a pattern like:

I have this code:

```
def get_right_arrow_pattern(max_cols)
    emoji = ""
    result = ""
    max_rows = max_cols
    for row in range(1, max_rows+1):
        for column in range(1, max_cols+1):
            result = "" + result
        result += str(emoji)
        print(result)
    return emoji
```

But I get this result:

```
None
```

This code is tricky because my homeowork does not allow print()to be used within the function or for loops instead I can only use it to show my results. I only used it in this code because it was the only thing that worked and came to mind and was semi-successful.

Comment: What value are you passing (max_cols) to get the required output? 3?

Comment: "The trick is" - what does this mean? Are you saying that your [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822) does not allow you to do this? Or do you mean that, according to *your analysis of the problem*, the code can't work properly if you do that? Or something else?

Comment: "why am I missing a few bottom rows or columns?" - In your own words, what part of the code is supposed to make those bottom rows? Step by step, how do you think it works? Step by step, how do you believe that you are getting the result that you currently do? What seems to be wrong, specifically?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel- What I mean to say is that its tricky to not use print within the for loops because my homework does not allow print() to be used but when I wrote this code it was the only thing that came to mind to use and worked, sort of. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I changed my statement to clarify what I mean to say, I don't want to confuse anyone any further so that's my bad. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Aha. I can no longer close this as a duplicate, but please read [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285) and [How can I use `return` to get back multiple values from a loop? Can I put them in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get your desired output by adding some lines to your existing code:

```py
def get_right_arrow_pattern(max_cols):
    emoji = ""
    result = ""
    max_rows = max_cols

    for row in range(1, max_rows+1):
        result += str(emoji)
        print(result)

    for row in range(1, max_rows):
        result = result[:-1] # This will remove the last character from the string
        print(result)

    return emoji
```

You can also get the same result without using the `print()` statement inside the function.

```py
def get_right_arrow_pattern(max_cols):
    emoji = ""
    result = ""
    max_rows = max_cols

    for row in range(1, max_rows+1):
        result += emoji*row
        result += "\n"

    for row in reversed(range(1, max_rows)):
        result += emoji*row
        result += "\n"

    return result
```

> **Note:** 
> `No_of_rows != No_of_columns` for this pattern. 
> Logically, `No_of_rows == (No_of_columns * 2) - 1`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: From the question I quote "The trick is I can't use print() within the function"

Comment: @DarkKnight Thank you for the correction. I've made some adjustments to my answer. Examine and, if necessary, recommend improvements.

Comment: @FuturistForever, thank you! This helped me a lot and solved my issue :D

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a list in your function, return that and print in the main program.

For example:

```
def get_right_arrow_pattern(max_cols, emoji = ''):
    return [emoji * i for i in range(1, max_cols+1)] + [emoji * i for i in range(max_cols-1, 0, -1)]

print(*get_right_arrow_pattern(3), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**