# Can you return a turtle using a function?

Tags: python, function, return, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Is there any way to use a function to create a turtle and then return the turtle to be used in a separate function?

I have an assignment to make a mosaic of squares, and I have a `main` function, `create_turtle` function, and `draw_square` function.  When I run my program, it works how it is supposed to, but as you can see, I have not used the `create_turtle` function. I just created the turtle in my `main` function.

Is there a way I could call my `create_turtle` function and somehow return the turtle to my main function?

```
def draw_square(rectangle, x, y, width, height):
    rectangle.penup()
    rectangle.goto(x,y)
    rectangle.fillcolor(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
    rectangle.pendown()
    rectangle.begin_fill()
    for sides in range(2):
        rectangle.forward(width)
        rectangle.right(90)
        rectangle.forward(height)
        rectangle.right(90)
    rectangle.end_fill()
    rectangle.penup()
    rectangle.goto(x+(width/2),y-(height/2))
    rectangle.stamp()

def create_turtle():
    stampy = turtle.Turtle()
    stampy.shape("turtle")
    stampy.hideturtle()
    stampy.speed(0)
    return(stampy)

def main():
    height = turtle.window_height()
    width = turtle.window_width()
    rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows for the mosaic: "))
    columns = int(input("Enter the number of columns for the mosaic: "))
    stampy = turtle.Turtle()
    stampy.shape("turtle")
    stampy.hideturtle()
    stampy.speed(0)
    y = height/2
    for row in range(rows):
        x = width/(-2)
        for column in range(columns):
            draw_square(stampy, x, y, width/columns, height/rows)
            x = x + (width/columns)
        y = y - (height/rows)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, after this code I only call the main() function, which then calls the draw_square() function

Comment: Before you use any `def` statements. That is when you can assign your turtle. But, you will have to use `global (turtle name)` at every `def` statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get ("return") a result (output) from a function? How can I use the result later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052793/how-do-i-get-return-a-result-output-from-a-function-how-can-i-use-the-res)