# Python code not replacing specified text, why?

Tags: python, replace

My code is intended to replace ":)" or ":(" with their corresponding emojis, but it doesn't. It returns the same text.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    x = input("Please enter your input ")
    convert(x)
    print(x)

def convert(x):
   x = x.replace(":)", "").replace(":(", "") 

main()
```

If I use print(convert(x)) it functions but I have no idea why the original doesn't work. I think convert(x) should change the text and print(x) should print the new str stored in the variable x. I can't figure it out, can anyone explain? Thank you

Comment: `x = ... ` This _rebinds_ the variable name `x` to a **local** variable inside the function.  This does **not** affect the parameter value in `main()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a result (output) from a function? How can I use the result later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052793/how-do-i-get-a-result-output-from-a-function-how-can-i-use-the-result-later)

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the transformed string and assign it back to the original variable (or another variable). Because strings are immutable, you can't modify them in-place, and overwriting a parameter's value inside the function scope doesn't affect the original variable that was passed from another scope:

```
def main():
    x = input("Please enter your input ")
    x = convert(x)
    print(x)

def convert(x):
    return x.replace(":)", "").replace(":(", "")
```

Having:

```
def f(x):
    x = 2 # this creates a new local variable `x`

x = 1
f(x) # this doesn't change the value of the above `x`
```