# Set a custom object attribute

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I was messing around with inherited classes and wondered if it was possible to set a custom object attribute using a method.
It would work something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
    def setCustAttr(self, name, value):
        #...
g=MyClass()
g.setCustAttr("var",5)
g.var+=6
g.var="text"
```

- Is there any way to do this?
- Could you use `exec("self."+string+"="+value)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python create object and add attributes to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827623/python-create-object-and-add-attributes-to-it)

Comment: Not a dupe of that question. That question is about `setattr` failing on `object`s. It's likely a dupe of something else.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean in addition to `g.var = 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments passed to `setCustAttr` are exactly the arguments you would pass to `setattr`.

```
def setCustAttr(self, name, value):
    setattr(self, name, value)
```

Why would you want a wrapper around `setattr`? You might try to perform some validation:

```
def setCustAttr(self, name, value):
    if name not in ['bar', 'baz']:
        raise ValueError("Custom attribute must be 'bar' or 'baz'")
    if name == 'bar' and value < 0:
        raise ValueError("'bar' attribute must be non-negative")
    if name == 'baz' and value % 2:
        raise ValueError("'baz' attribute must be even")

    setattr(self, name, value)
```

However, this doesn't prevent the user of your class from ignoring your `setCustAttr` method and assigning directly to the object:

```
g = MyClass()
g.bar = -5  # Negative bar!
g.baz = 3   # Odd baz!
g.quux = 2  # Non-bar/baz attribute!
```

Python has deep magic for providing more control over how attributes are set on an object (see `__slots__`, `__{get,set}attr__`, `__getattribute__`, properties, etc), but generally, they aren't used merely to prevent the examples shown above. The Python way is to just document how an instance of your class should be used, and trust the user to abide by your instructions. (And if they don't, *caveat emptor*.)

Comment: So there would be no need for another method?

Comment: Not really. You might use a wrapper like this to provide validation. `g.setCustAttr("var", 5)` might first check that the value is greater than 0 (raising a `ValueError` if not), or that the first argument is from a restricted set of names (simulating part of the function of the `__slots__` attribute). However, a user of your class could still just ignore your method and write `g.var = 5` anyway.

Comment: So you would evaluate the new value before setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is what the `setattr` function does:

```
setattr(g, 'var', 5)
# g.var is now 5
```