# python why the enum has this Attribute

Tags: python, enums

this is my code

```
#coding:utf8 

from enum import Enum


class Color(Enum):
    red=1
    green=2
    black=3


Color.red.price=30.0
Color.black.price=40.0
Color.green.price=40.0

Color.green.xxx = True
```

why the color.red has this attribute ,such as price or xxx or anything?
Thanks for you answer

Comment: I would expect this to cause an error. It shouldn't have those attributes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Funnily enough, I tried this and it works.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I tried it, but QPython on my phone isn't running a new enough version to have the module. I looked over the docs and can't find a price field. Does python allow attributes to be added on the fly, JS-style with a special tweak?

Comment: You're just adding attributes to it. Nothing fancy there.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, it would seem there is no protection against this sort of thing.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The docs suggest that Enums are special. "Even though we use the class syntax to create Enums, Enums are not normal Python classes. See How are Enums different? for more details." My Python is too rusty to understand wtf it's talking about after that though.

Comment: Wait, my python must be really rusty. I just created a new bare class and was able to do this. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Enums. Never knew Python allows attributes to be added at runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827623/python-create-object-and-add-attributes-to-it

Comment: The type of `Color.red` is an `<enum 'Color'>`, which is an object, why does adding an attribute seem fancy? @Carcigenicate python is a dynamic language, you can add attributes to any object even functions: `def f(): pass; f.a = 10` is perfectly legal.

Comment: @AChampion Wow. Not sure how I missed that during the year that I wrote Python. Good to know!

Comment: @AChampion you're right

Answer (score 1):

`Color.red` has a `price` attribute because you gave it one.  The only (mostly) immutable parts of an `Enum` member are its `name` and `value`.

Note that `Color.red` does not have an `xxx` attribute as you only assigned that one to `Color.green`.

---

If you really want to disallow adding extra attributes at run-time, please see [Python enum prevent invalid attribute assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54274002/208880).

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the `Color` class objects don't have such attribute.

What's happening here is that you are creating those attribute, which could then be used. Apparently, python being dynamic and stuff allows such a thing.

If we see objects as arrays of values and references, what you'd be doing here is appending another value (or reference) to the current object.

I did a quick and dirty example using [this online interpreter](https://repl.it/languages/python3) :

```
from enum import Enum

class names(Enum):
    Paul=1
    Robert=2,
    Jean=3,
    Charles=4

names.Paul.price = 25
print(names.Paul.price)  # works, as we just added the price poperty.
print(isinstance(names.Paul, names))  # returns true, we don't lose property.
print(names.Robert.price)  # AttributeError, we didn't add it.
```

Comment: Omg, it was getting late and I realised I had described behavior without explaining much. 

Will probably edit later on.

Answer (score 0):

This is just like any other object. You can add new attributes to an class object(those attributes belongs only to the object)

```
class A:
  foo1="bar"

a=A()
a.foo2="bar2"
print(a.foo2)
print(A.foo1) 
print(A.foo2) # gives an attribute error
```

In case of enum

```
 from enum import Enum
   class A(Enum): 
..   a="enum" 
..
```

each member is an Enum object

```
   dir(A.a)
=> ['__class__', '__doc__', '__module__', 'name', 'value']

   dir(Enum)
=> ['__class__', '__doc__', '__members__', '__module__']
```

Hence just like any other class object you can add attribute to the object

```
A.a.foo1="bar1"
```