# Python Enum prevent invalid attribute assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

When I use the Functional API to create an Enum, I get back an Enum object that allows arbitrary assignment (i.e. it has a `__dict__`):

```py
e = enum.Enum('Things',[('foo',1),('bar',2)])
e.baz = 3
```

The item does not appear in the list:

```py
list(e)
[<foo.foo: 1>, <foo.bar: 2>]
```

But it can still be referenced:

```py
if thing == e.baz: ...
```

Now while it seems unlikely to ever occur, one of the reasons I want to use an Enum is to prevent spelling mistakes and string literals, and for those things to be caught when a module is imported or as early as possible.

Is there a way to dynamically build an Enum that behaves more like a `__slots__` object that does not allow arbitrary attributes to be assigned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make an enum class fully 'read-only', all that is required is a meta class that uses the [`__setattr__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) that prevents *all* attribute assignments. Because the metaclass is attached to the class *after* it is created, there is no issue with assigning the proper enumerated values.

Like Ethan's answer, I'm using the `EnumMeta` class as a base for the custom metaclass:

```
from enum import EnumMeta, Enum

class FrozenEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    "Enum metaclass that freezes an enum entirely"
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, classdict):
        classdict['__frozenenummeta_creating_class__'] = True
        enum = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, classdict)
        del enum.__frozenenummeta_creating_class__
        return enum

    def __call__(cls, value, names=None, *, module=None, **kwargs):
        if names is None:  # simple value lookup
            return cls.__new__(cls, value)
        enum = Enum._create_(value, names, module=module, **kwargs)
        enum.__class__ = type(cls)
        return enum

    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        members = cls.__dict__.get('_member_map_', {})
        if hasattr(cls, '__frozenenummeta_creating_class__') or name in members:
            return super().__setattr__(name, value)
        if hasattr(cls, name):
            msg = "{!r} object attribute {!r} is read-only"
        else:
            msg = "{!r} object has no attribute {!r}"
        raise AttributeError(msg.format(cls.__name__, name))

    def __delattr__(cls, name):
        members = cls.__dict__.get('_member_map_', {})
        if hasattr(cls, '__frozenenummeta_creating_class__') or name in members:
            return super().__delattr__(name)
        if hasattr(cls, name):
            msg = "{!r} object attribute {!r} is read-only"
        else:
            msg = "{!r} object has no attribute {!r}"
        raise AttributeError(msg.format(cls.__name__, name))

class FrozenEnum(Enum, metaclass=FrozenEnumMeta):
    pass
```

The above distinguishes between attributes that are already available and new attributes, for ease of diagnosing. It also blocks attribute *deletion*, which is probably just as important!

It also provides both the metaclass and a `FrozenEnum` *base class* for enumerations; use this instead of `Enum`.

To freeze a sample `Color` enumeration:

```
>>> class Color(FrozenEnum):
...     red = 1
...     green = 2
...     blue = 3
...
>>> list(Color)
[<Color.red: 1>, <Color.green: 2>, <Color.blue: 3>]
>>> Color.foo = 'bar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    # ...
AttributeError: 'Color' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> Color.red = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
    # ...
Cannot reassign members.
>>> del Color.red
Traceback (most recent call last):
    # ...
AttributeError: Color: cannot delete Enum member.
```

Note that **all** attribute changes are disallowed, no new attributes permitted, and deletions are blocked too. When names are enum members, we delegate to the original `EnumMeta` handling to keep the error messages stable.

If your enum uses properties that alter attributes on the enum class, you'd either have to whitelist those, or allow for names starting with a single underscore to be set; in `__setattr__` determine what names would be permissible to set and use `super().__setattr__(name, value)` for those exceptions, just like the code now distinguishes between class construction and later alterations by using a flag attribute.

The above class can be used just like `Enum()` to programmatically create an enumeration:

```
e = FrozenEnum('Things', [('foo',1), ('bar',2)]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> e = FrozenEnum('Things', [('foo',1), ('bar',2)])
>>> e
<enum 'Things'>
>>> e.foo = 'bar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    # ...
AttributeError: Cannot reassign members.
```

Comment: @Martijn Pieters♦ "It also provides both the metaclass and a FrozenEnum base class for enumerations; ***use this instead of Enum***"?  The  ***Enum*** provided by `enum34` could guarantee unique,constant values and no reassignment are permitted. I can't see why to use the `FrozenEnum` other than `Enum`? Could you please explain that in detail for me?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters♦ Why `Color.black=1;` is permitted when given `class Color(FrozenEnum):
...     red = 1
...     green = 2
...     blue = 3
...`. I think there is no difference with defining the `Color` as a `Enum` type.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily easy, but possible.  We need to create a new `EnumMeta` type<sup>1</sup>, create the `Enum` normally, then reassign the type after the `Enum` is created:

```
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta

class FrozenEnum(EnumMeta):
    "prevent creation of new attributes"
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name not in self._member_map_:
            raise AttributeError('%s %r has no attribute %r'
                % (self.__class__.__name__, self.__name__, name))
        return super().__getattr__(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__dict__ or name in self._member_map_:
            return super().__setattr__(name, value)
        raise AttributeError('%s %r has no attribute %r'
                % (self.__class__.__name__, self.__name__, name))

class Color(Enum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3

Color.__class__ = FrozenEnum
```

and in use:

```
>>> type(Color)
<class 'FrozenEnum'>

>>> list(Color)
[<Color.red: 1>, <Color.green: 2>, <Color.blue: 3>]

>>> Color.blue
<Color.blue: 3>

>>> Color.baz = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: FrozenEnum 'Color' has no attribute 'baz'

>>> Color.baz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'FrozenEnum' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

Trying to reassign a member still gives the friendlier error:

```
>>> Color.blue = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: Cannot reassign members.
```

In order to make the class reassignment a little easier, we can write a decorator to encapsulate the process:

```
def freeze(enum_class):
    enum_class.__class__ = FrozenEnum
    return enum_class
```

and in use:

```
@freeze
class Color(Enum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

Note that it is still possible to overwrite ordinary attributes, such as functions:

```
@freeze
class Color(Enum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
    def huh(self):
        print("Huh, I am %s!" % self.name)
```

and in use:

```
>>> Color.huh
<function Color.huh at 0x7f7d54ae96a8>

>>> Color.blue.huh()
Huh, I am blue!

>>> Color.huh = 3
>>> Color.huh
3
>>> Color.blue.huh()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Even that can be blocked, but I'll leave that (for now) as an exercise for someone else.

---

<sup>1</sup>  This is only the second case I have seen where subclassing `EnumMeta` is required.  For the other, see [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43730305/208880).

*Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.*

Comment: All you need to make your version properly frozen is for your `__setattr__` hook to *always* raise an `AttributeError`, rather than allow for setting specific attributes. That's fine because you assign the metaclass **after** the class has been created.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Yes, I know.  :)  I was hoping a newer user would see that and get the rep bump from the bounty.

Comment: Sorry if I stepped in where you hoped others would :-) I added a full metaclass / class combo and blocked deletions too, would that soften the disappointment a little? :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well.... if you clean up the tracebacks (similarly to mine), and modify `__delattr__` and `__setattr__` to pass through attempts to delete/change member values to `EnumMeta` (so the user gets the member-related error instead of the generic read-only error), then I'll be happy.  :)  Oh, and thanks for catching the `__delattr__` case.