# How to create an indexable and sliceable enum with string values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a file like this:

```
class Level(Enum):
    prerequisite_level: Optional["Level"]
    dependent_level: Optional["Level"]
    lower_priority_levels: List["Level"]
    greater_priority_levels: List["Level"]

    DATA_CHECK = "data check"
    DESIGN_CHECK = "design check"
    ALERT = "alert"
```

The enum values are in a specific order, and based on each of those levels I need to be able to get the previous one, the next one, and all the previous and next ones. I believe I need to be able to index the levels numerically to get these values, so I've added a constant to be able to do this:

```
INCREASING_PRIORITY_LEVELS: List[Level] = list(Level)

for priority_level_index, threshold_level in enumerate(Level):
    if priority_level_index > 0:
        threshold_level.prerequisite_level = Level[priority_level_index - 1]
    else:
        threshold_level.prerequisite_level = None

    if priority_level_index < len(Level) - 1:
        threshold_level.dependent_level = Level[priority_level_index + 1]
    else:
        threshold_level.dependent_level = None

    threshold_level.lower_priority_levels = Level[:priority_level_index]
    threshold_level.greater_priority_levels = Level[priority_level_index + 1:]
```

This is clunky, and I'd like to get rid of this constant. Do I need to implement `__getitem__` or something to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Level(Enum):

    prerequisite_level: Optional["Level"]
    dependent_level: Optional["Level"]
    lower_priority_levels: List["Level"]
    greater_priority_levels: List["Level"]

    DATA_CHECK = "data check"
    DESIGN_CHECK = "design check"
    ALERT = "alert"
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the above: ... [comments clarified that the first four should be attributes, and `prequisite` and `dependent` are the previous and following members, respectively].

The solution is to modify previous members as the current member is being initialized (the trick being that the current member isn't added to the parent `Enum` until after the member's creation and initialization).  Here is the solution using the stdlib's `Enum`<sup>1</sup> (Python 3.6 and later):

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Level(str, Enum):
    #
    def __init__(self, name):
        # create priority level lists
        self.lower_priority_levels = list(self.__class__._member_map_.values())
        self.greater_priority_levels = []
        # update previous members' greater priority list
        for member in self.lower_priority_levels:
            member.greater_priority_levels.append(self)
        # and link prereq and dependent
        self.prerequisite = None
        self.dependent = None
        if self.lower_priority_levels:
            self.prerequisite = self.lower_priority_levels[-1]
            self.prerequisite.dependent = self
    #
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values, *args, **kwds):
        return (name.lower().replace('_',' '), ) + args
    #
    DATA_CHECK = auto()
    DESIGN_CHECK = auto()
    ALERT = auto()
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Level)
[<Level.DATA_CHECK: 'data check'>, <Level.DESIGN_CHECK: 'design check'>, <Level.ALERT: 'alert'>]

>>> Level.DATA_CHECK.prerequisite
None

>>> Level.DATA_CHECK.dependent
<Level.DESIGN_CHECK: 'design check'>

>>> Level.DESIGN_CHECK.prerequisite
<Level.DATA_CHECK: 'data check'>

>>> Level.DESIGN_CHECK.dependent
<Level.ALERT: 'alert'>

>>> Level.ALERT.prerequisite
<Level.DESIGN_CHECK: 'design check'>

>>> Level.ALERT.dependent
None
```

Note:  If you don't want to see the name twice, a custom `__repr__` can show just the enum and member names:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s.%s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)
```

then you'll see:

```
>>> Level.DESIGN_CHECK
<Level.DESIGN_CHECK>
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If using Python 3.5 or older you need to use [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>2</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Level values are used as field values in an ORM and are returned from an API, so they shouldn't be integers. You can only create (an instance with) a design check level when there is (an instance with) a data check level, hence `Level.DESIGN_CHECK.prerequisite == Level.DATA_CHECK and Level.DATA_CHECK.dependent == Level.DESIGN_CHECK`.

Comment: @l0b0:  Ah, okay.  Updated my answer to better match your question.

Comment: @l0b0: Woops -- add `, name` into the `__init__`.

Comment: @l0b0: Did a little trimming -- updated the `_generate_next_value_` and removed the `__new__` method.

Comment: This might be asking too much, but why does `_generate_next_value_` not have `self` as the first argument? This breaks flake8 linting: "N805 first argument of a method should be named 'self'". Also, `mypy` seems to think `self.__class__._member_map_` has type `Level`.

Comment: @l0b0: `_generate_next_value_` is a static method -- when it's called `self` doesn't yet exist; try decorating it with `@staticmethod`.  Not sure what's up with `mypy` -- try asking a question about that, and/or filing an issue on [`mypy`s issue tracker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues).

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass `EnumMeta` to override the `__getitem__` method with additional conditions to return a list of `Enum` values or a specific `Enum` value based on the given index, and create a subclass of `Enum` with the aforementioned subclass of `EnumMeta` as the metaclass, so that any subclass of this new subclass of `Enum` can be indexed as desired:

```
from itertools import islice
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta

class IndexableEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __getitem__(cls, index):
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return [cls._member_map_[i] for i in islice(cls._member_map_, index.start, index.stop, index.step)]
        if isinstance(index, int):
            return cls._member_map_[next(islice(cls._member_map_, index, index + 1))]
        return cls._member_map_[index]

class IndexableEnum(Enum, metaclass=IndexableEnumMeta):
    pass

class Level(IndexableEnum):
    DATA_CHECK = "data check"
    DESIGN_CHECK = "design check"
    ALERT = "alert"
```

so that `Level[1:3]` returns:

```
[<Level.DESIGN_CHECK: 'design check'>, <Level.ALERT: 'alert'>]
```

and `Level[1]` returns:

```
Level.DESIGN_CHECK
```

(Credit goes to @EthanFurman for pointing out the viability of subclassing `EnumMeta`.)

Comment: Yes it does, since it overrides `__getitem__` of the meta class that generates `Enum` class instances.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to override `__getitem__` of just one specific class then.

Comment: Fantastic work. I personally wouldn't trade my workaround for this amount of complexity, but others might.

Comment: The complexity of creating modified copies the `EnumMeta` and `Enum` classes can be hidden into a separate module if the goal is to make your user-facing subclass `Level` as clean as possible.

Comment: While I don't encourage [subclassing `EnumMeta`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43730305/208880), it is much easier to do that than what you are doing here.

Comment: @EthanFurman Thanks for your input. Subclassing `EnumMeta` was actually the first thing that came to my mind, but upon further inspection I realized that it would not be a viable approach because `Enum` specifically uses `EnumMeta` as a metaclass, which means that one would have to write a new `Enum` class to be able to use this new subclass of `EnumMeta` as a metaclass. Furthermore, the `EnumMeta._get_mixins` method has a validation check of `if not issubclass(base, Enum):` that hard-codes `Enum` as a required base class, so using a new `Enum` class would fail at this validation.

Comment: @EthanFurman ...which is why I had to parse the source and modify the AST in order to make these hard-coded names to the names of the new classes. Please feel free to try implementing such a subclass yourself and let me know if you find a way to do it without having to modify the source or a copy of the AST.

Comment: [Dynamic member creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43730305/208880);  [Preventing attribute assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54274002/208880);  [Making an Abstract Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56131308/208880).

Comment: As you'll notice from the above examples, creating a new `Enum` with a subclassed `EnumMeta` is as simple as `class MyEnum(Enum, metaclass=MyNewMetaclass)`

Comment: @EthanFurman Thanks. I did consider subclassing `Enum` with `metaclass` pointing to the new subclass of `EnumMeta` as well but did not actually try it only because I wrongly thought that it would result in this new subclass of `Enum` becoming just a class of enumerated constants. I've rewritten my answer as suggested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another version building on @blhsing's answer with types and support for finding the index of a member. Unfortunately Mypy does not fully support the metaclass so the type variable is overly generic.

```py
import enum
import itertools
from typing import TypeVar

_EnumMemberT = TypeVar("_EnumMemberT")


class _IndexableEnumType(enum.EnumType):
    def __getitem__(self: type[_EnumMemberT], name: str | int) -> _EnumMemberT:
        if isinstance(name, int):
            try:
                return next(itertools.islice(enum.EnumType.__iter__(self), name, None))
            except StopIteration:
                raise IndexError("enum index out of range") from None
        return enum.EnumType.__getitem__(self, name)

    def index(self: type[_EnumMemberT], name: str) -> int:
        for index, member in enumerate(enum.EnumType.__iter__(self)):
            if member.name == name:  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
                return index
        raise ValueError(f"'{name}' is not in enum")


class IndexableEnum(enum.Enum, metaclass=_IndexableEnumType):
    pass
```

Then one can declare an `IndexableEnum` as per usual and use indices as you would with a list:

```
>>> class MyEnum(IndexableEnum):
...     Foo = "bar"
...     Baz = "qux"
... 
>>> 
>>> MyEnum[0] 
<MyEnum.Foo: 'bar'>
>>>                    
>>> MyEnum.index('Foo')
0
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

A possible alternative to achieve the same result in terms of usage would be to use `collections.namedtuple` instead:

```
from collections import namedtuple
LevelSequence = namedtuple('Level', ('DATA_CHECK', 'DESIGN_CHECK', 'ALERT'))
Level = LevelSequence('data check', 'design check', 'alert')
```

So that:

- `Level.DESIGN_CHECK` and `Level[1]` both return `'design check'`, and
- `Level[1:3]` returns `('design check', 'alert')`