# Python object initialization bug. Or am I misunderstanding how objects work?

Tags: python, mutable, arguments

```
  1 import sys
  2 
  3 class dummy(object):
  4     def __init__(self, val):
  5         self.val = val
  6 
  7 class myobj(object):
  8     def __init__(self, resources):
  9         self._resources = resources
 10 
 11 class ext(myobj):
 12     def __init__(self, resources=[]):
 13         #myobj.__init__(self, resources)
 14         self._resources = resources
 15 
 16 one = ext()
 17 one._resources.append(1)
 18 two = ext()
 19 
 20 print one._resources
 21 print two._resources
 22 
 23 sys.exit(0)
```

This will print the reference to the object assigned to `one._resources` for both `one` and `two` objects. I would think that `two` would be an empty array as it is clearly setting it as such if it's not defined when creating the object. Uncommenting `myobj.__init__(self, resources)` does the same thing.  Using `super(ext, self).__init__(resources)` also does the same thing.

The only way I can get it to work is if I use the following:

```
two = ext(dummy(2))
```

I shouldn't have to manually set the default value when creating the object to make this work. Or maybe I do. Any thoughts?

I tried this using Python 2.5 and 2.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change

```
def __init__(self, resources=[]):
    self._resources = resources
```

to

```
def __init__(self, resources=None):
    if resources is None:
        resources = []
    self._resources = resources
```

and all will be better. This is a detail in the way default arguments are handled if they're mutable. There's some more information in the discussion section of [this page](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502206/).

Comment: +1: Do not use a mutable object (like a list) as a default value in a method function definition.  This is a standard n00b mistake.

Comment: I kind of understand the answer, but my brain just don't get it:) Could someone include a metaphor or something? Why is the defaul argument kept in memory if they are mutable. ... :-(

Comment: Ok, I'm lazy, I don't want to read all those links you've posted already :(   Are those like instance variables or something?

Comment: @Oscar Reyes: Here's the simple rule.  Never use a mutable object as a default value.  Default values only have a single copy and it's shared every time the default is used.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that the default value is evaluated at function definition time. This means that the same list object is shared between instances. See the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for more discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495666/how-to-define-a-class-in-python/1495740#1495740) for a discussion of how to setup a class from `__init__()`.  You have encountered a well-known quirk of Python: you are trying to set up a mutable, and your mutable is being evaluated once when `__init__()` is compiled.  The standard workaround is:

```
class ext(myobj):
    def __init__(self, resources=None):
        if resources is None:
            resources = []
        #myobj.__init__(self, resources)
        self._resources = resources
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/controlflow.html:

> The default value is evaluated only
>   once. This makes a difference when the
>   default is a mutable object such as a
>   list, dictionary, or instances of most
>   classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known](http://www.ferg.org/projects/python_gotchas.html#contents_item_6) Python [gotcha](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/16/python-insight-beware-of-mutable-default-values-for-arguments/).

You have to avoid using a mutable object on the call of a function/method.

> The objects that provide the default values **are not created at the time that the function/method is called**. **They are created at the time that the statement that defines the function is executed**. (See the discussion at [Default arguments in Python: two easy blunders](http://www.deadlybloodyserious.com/2008/05/default-argument-blunders/): *"Expressions in default arguments are calculated when the function is defined, not when it’s called."*)
>
> This behavior is not a wart in the Python language. It really is a feature, not a bug. There are times when you really do want to use mutable default arguments. One thing they can do (for example) is retain a list of results from previous invocations, something that might be very handy.
>
> But for most programmers — especially beginning Pythonistas — this behavior is a gotcha. So for most cases we adopt the following rules.
>
> - **Never use a mutable object** — that is: a list, a dictionary, or a class instance — as the default value of an argument.
> - Ignore rule 1 only if you really, really, REALLY know what you're doing.
>
> So... we plan always to follow rule #1. Now, the question is how to do it... how to code functionF in order to get the behavior that we want.
>
> Fortunately, the solution is straightforward. The mutable objects used as defaults are replaced by `None`, and then the arguments are tested for `None`.

---

> So how can one do it correctly? One solution is **avoid using mutable default values for arguments**. But this is hardly satisfactory, as from time to time a new list is a useful default. There are some complex solutions like defining a decorator for functions that deep-copies all arguments. This is an overkill, and the problem can be solved easily as follows:

```
class ext(myobj):
    def __init__(self, resources=None):
        if not resources:
            resources = []
        self._resources = resources
```