# Default value in a function in Python

Tags: python, default-value

I am noticing the following:

```
class c:
  def __init__(self, data=[]):
    self._data=data
a=c()
b=c()
a._data.append(1)
print b._data
[1]
```

Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: Please read the markup documentation to see how to correctly format code.  It's on the right side of the page.  Please update your question to indent the code 4 spaces.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011431/python-things-one-must-avoid, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534407/python-object-intialization-bug-or-am-i-misunderstanding-how-objects-work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651154/why-are-default-arguments-evaluated-at-definition-time-in-python

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's correct behavior.

However, from your question, it appears that it's not what you expected.

If you want it to match your expectations, be aware of the following:

Rule 1.  Do not use mutable objects as default values.

```
def anyFunction( arg=[] ):
```

Will not create a fresh list object.  The default list object for `arg` will be shared all over the place.

Similarly

```
def anyFunction( arg={} ):
```

will not create a fresh dict object.  This default dict will be shared.

```
class MyClass( object ):
    def __init__( self, arg= None ):
        self.myList= [] if arg is None else arg
```

That's a common way to provide a default argument value that is a fresh, empty list object.

Comment: `Will never work.` is a bit harsh. `Won't give you a new empty mutable object on each call`, seems a little more balanced. If you know this happens you might actually want to use this behaviour.

Comment: @MattH: Reusing the same mutable object via a default value is so odd that it defies finding a sensible use case.  It's a *default* value, so it may (or may not) get used as such depending on the client's use of the interface.  It would be so hard to diagnose problems with this that I stand by my original formulation.  Especially for n00bz.

Comment: You should add an example of how to work around this. Otherwise the answer is good and correct.

Comment: There's a sensible use case for almost everything. For mutable default values I'd choose a simple memoization strategy, for example as described by Alex Martelli here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651154/why-are-default-arguments-evaluated-at-definition-time-in-python/1651284#1651284

Comment: @Scott Griffiths: While there's a use case, I would debate "sensible".  Yes, it works, but so does unreadable spaghetti code.  Using mutable objects as *default* values is a bad idea.  In the example question, the default value syntax is used to provide a hidden memoization context; it doesn't fit the usual design patterns for "default" because there is o sensible reason to provide a real value.

Answer (score 1):

Always make functions like this then:

```
def __init__ ( self, data = None ):
    if data is None:
       data = []

    self._data = data
```

Alternatively you could also use `data = data or []`, but that prevents the user from passing *empty* parameters (`''`, `0`, `False` etc.).

Comment: Of course you can also do `if not data: data = []`.

Comment: your example `data = data or []` works just fine for empty lists being passed. You'd be saying `data` will be `[] or []` so it will look at the first one and see that it evaluates to "false", then it will take the other value.

Comment: I know, my point was that when you pass `False` for example, `[]` will be used as the value, although you passed `False`.