# How do can I fix this issue about 'NoneType' error?

Tags: python, jupyter

```
class lights(object):
    l1 = lights()
    l1.color = "blue"
    l1.quantity = 50
​
    l2 = lights()
    l2.color = "red"
    l2.quantity = 50    ​
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-1ae6b23b2a3d> in <module>
----> 1 class lights(object):
      2     l1 = lights()
      3     l1.color = "blue"
      4     l1.quantity = 50
      5
```

in lights()
          1 class lights(object):
          2     l1 = lights()
    ----> 3     l1.color = "blue"
          4     l1.quantity = 50
          5

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'color'
```

Comment: `lights` shouldn't even be defined yet. This apparently *re*defines `lights`, which previously was a function that returns `None` when called.

Comment: showing more code could be helpfull.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This code has a few problems, probably makes sense to understand your main aim in order to better help ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I define a class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495666/how-can-i-define-a-class-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are wanting a constructor to define what properties lights may have:

```py
class lights(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.color = ""
    self.quantity = 0


l1 = lights()
l1.color = "blue"
l1.quantity = 50
l2 = lights()
l2.color = "red"
l2.quantity = 50
```

This will run and create two `lights` instances.

Comment: `class lights (object):` is entirely correct, though inheriting from `object` is neither useful nor necessary in Python 3. The problem is that the `l1` object creation as a class global attempts to instantiate the class before it has been defined.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you, I'm not a big Python buff, will correct answer

Comment: ok so Im still a bit perplexed. So I need to define  l1 first and then go ahead with this? @tripleee

Comment: @Sean you were trying to create a `lights` instance inside of the declaration of `lights`, which would cause an infinite loop (if it worked, but it doesn't, because `lights` doesn't exist until after the declaration is over)

Python is a whitespace based language, the way you had the code indented, you were trying to create `l1` and `l2` inside the declaration of `lights`

Comment: Basically, all I have done is move your code creating `l1` and `l2` outside of the declaration of `lights` so that `lights` exists before they are created, and I added a constructor so that `lights` have `color` and `quantity` members.

Comment: ah ok that helped a bit. still somewhat perplexed but this helped. guess I need to keep practicing and understanding the order

Comment: It would perhaps be more natural and idiomatic if the  `__init__` method took `color` and `quantity` keyword arguments - up to you and your applications' requirements whether these can be optional.

Comment: one more question @tripleee how do I make a space print('There are ' + l1.color + str(l1.quantity)) since the output looks like this There are blue50

Comment: Uh, you add a space where you need one. Maybe look at `format()` and/or f-strings too.

Comment: nvm. I figured it out. with  + '  ' +